# Accepting an answer should automatically upvote it as well

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, voting, accepted-answer

Is there ever a case where you would want to accept an answer, but not upvote it?

I can't think of a single situation where this would be the case.. So would it not make sense to have the "Accept" button upvote the answer too?

Comment: There are many new users on SO who accept questions but don't up-vote. It almost seems like this should be automatic... if the answer is the accepted answer, it must have also been helpful, no? I don't want to slap the wrist or explain to every new user who accepts my answer when the answer has 0 up-votes (and sometimes all answers have 0 up-votes).

Comment: I suppose some users think that accepting is enough and they don't need to be too generous, but I would guess that most just don't know the difference. If the up-vote is automatic then the ones who think accepting is enough could easily undo their up-vote (the up-vote shouldn't be done without telling them).

Comment: To upvote, you both need to meet a rep requirement and be registered. This is not a problem on SO, but on the other sites, not everyone wants to go through the hassle of signing up just to give an up-vote.

Comment: I've had people comment that it solved their problem but they neither accepted nor upvoted. sob sob.. :'(

Comment: Some OPs even copy the correct answer from an answerer. Then OP posts it as an answer by him/herself. But never upvotes or accept the correct answer in the first place though ;) had multiple of those..

Comment: [Related request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196780)

Comment: Well if this was implemented the unsung hero badge would become almost unobtainable.

Comment: I accepted an answer but ran out of votes for the day. Then I voted after midnight GMT. So there could be a problem with giving yourself >40 votes per day via accepting.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Since it is simple enough to cast an upvote and accept the answer, I don't a see a reason to constrain the user in this manner. I agree, I've never had a situation where I wasn't upvoting along with accepting. But, everyone has a different reason/rationale for upvoting, so I don't think the system should force that upvote.

Comment: For the people that don't know the difference, or couldn't be bothered to click twice, I think an automatic up-vote makes sense. For the people that *know* they don't want to both accept and up-vote, it is also simple enough to click the up-vote button again. Overall I think this experience is better than expecting *every* user to know the difference.

Comment: As someone who's relatively new to SO, it honestly didn't occur to me that I should upvote an answer that I've accepted. I assumed that accepting an answer that's useful to me was the proper way to express my sentiment of thanks. I'll do it from now on, but I can definitely see the rationale for having this be the default behavior.

Comment: I personally select and upvote only when the answer completely resolves the issue. For partial resolution I select as correct. For merely putting me on the right track I only upvote.

Comment: @fredsbend I hope that when you receive such an answer and upvote it, that you also come back, write up a complete answer of your own (that you came up with after being put on the right track), and accept it, too.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I'm much more liberal now with voting. Pretty much everyone gets an upvote unless it looked like there was no effort or spreading of knowledge, or, of course, if it was completely wrong. I currently only have one question without an accepted answer (because it is unanswered). I actually prefer to comment on the post that helped and let them know, then they can edit. Like I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18586274/1934286). Optionally, I could edit the post myself and add those last few steps that I stumbled on.

Comment: So for those of us that think StackOverflow should at least remind the user to upvote in addition to accepting the answer, how would we go about petitioning the StackOverflow management to actually make that change?

Comment: On meta sites, accepting usually shows the community opinion, whereas upvoting shows one's own opinion. Those aren't necessarily the same.

Comment: this remains a significant problem til today - users not familiar with stack will just upvote without accepting the answer. the right solution should be you can only accept an answer on a question you asked-which also upvotes the answer.only then should you be allowed to upvote anything else. the flow is awkward

Comment: downvoted because, as has been said, for one, new users may not think about it, and two, it's easy enough to undo the upvote, in what I'm sure are the rare cases where they want to accept but not upvote.

Comment: Very much disagree with this. I have a lot of accepted answers that were not upvoted, often from new users (which are a common user type for some tags I often answer). I don't want to comment and ask the person to upvote as that seems tacky, but it's really annoying getting lots of accepted answered but not getting upvotes that would count for my tag badges.

Answer (score 122):

I must have more than <del>40 answers</del> (July 2009), make that <del>**150 answers**</del>, (December 2010),
actually <del>**260 answers**</del> (June 2012), rather <del>**408 answers**</del> (July 2013), or <del>**603 answers**</del> (August 2014), err <del>**941 answers**</del> (August 2016), well... <del>**1020 answers**</del> (July 2017), confirmed: <del>**1169 answers**</del> (August 2018), indeed <del>**1273 answers**</del> (June 2019), wait: <del>**1417 answers**</del> (Sept. 2020), now <del>**1503 answers**</del> (Sept. 2021), updated **1591 answers** (Sept. 2022) on **non-wiki questions, accepted but not upvoted**.
<sup><sup>Mmmm, I see a trend here...</sup></sup>

[Real-time accepted, non-upvoted answers for me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6309+%09isaccepted%3Ayes+score%3A0+%09wiki%3Ano+%09is%3Aanswer) (compare it [with yours](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me%20%09isaccepted:yes%20score:0%20%09wiki:no%20%09is:answer)).

Those questions are often posted  by "occasional" users with very few reputation points.
Most of them never accept an answer.
Some finally get the tick thingy, but completely miss the upvote ("I have accepted the answer, now, why would I be supposed to do something *else*?")

As I said in the meta question "[What’s the single biggest barrier to entry on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/481/whats-the-single-biggest-barrier-to-entry-on-so/521#521)", they simply do not know (and do not care).

Even the new (January 2013) [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about) helps only moderately (but it is certainly an improvement).

---

> So would it not make sense to have the "Accept" button upvote the question too?

Even though I would benefit from such a feature, I am **not** in favor of that modification.

- Accept is for accepting an answer.
- Upvote is for upvoting an answer.

Keeping them separate seems right in term of UI design, following the ["Don't make me Think" rules](https://cynng.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/book-review-notes-dont-make-me-think-krug/), as in "making things obvious vs. hidden information".

Comment: Which is why the *default* should be an automatic upvote for accepts. Any user conscious about it could very easily cancel the up.

Comment: @ohadsc: see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/: you need to *encourage* them to vote, not vote for them ;)

Comment: @VonC Couldn't this be a step towards that encouragement? have a popup that says "an upvote has been cast in your name. to learn more about upvotes click here"

Comment: @ohadsc: any automatic action made "in the user's name" is likely to be perceived at first as an unwelcome surprise. A message reminding them that an upvote is *also* possible (if they have 15 rep) is good. But forcing an upvote seems wrong.

Comment: I'd go with the reminder message as well. But the current situation is absurd - half of my accepted answers have 0 upvotes, and I'm sure it's not because the users consciously avoided upvoting

Comment: @ohadsc: most of mines (140 accepted answers with 0 votes!) comes from users who hadn't 15 rep at the time and couldn't vote anyway;)

Comment: That's a good point. Perhaps a mechanism could be installed to allow users with < 15 rep to upvote answers only for their own questions

Comment: I have upvoted the question to get them past the 15 rep so they could upvote me. Is that wrong? idk. I can't help it. I think I'm addicted to rep.

Comment: I just started on StackExchange a week ago and encountered the problem of finding useful questions and answers (whether to my own questions or others') that I wanted to upvote but couldn't. As a solution, I temporarily favorited all of those questions. Then today, when I finally got to 15 rep, I opened all of those favorited links and upvoted the questions and answers I couldn't before.

Comment: @VonC for how long you plan to update that list? ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman for as long as I am on this site. And I am on this site every day (http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309)

Comment: Lol. Your post was one of the first I read on MSO/MSE and it is still one of the posts that got me thinking.

Comment: How does "Don't make the think" lead to the conclusion that you should force the user to think about two separate actions (upvoting/accepting) and the very nuanced distinctions between them, rather than just making the site conform to their mental model ("this was a good answer")?

Comment: @SteveBennett I would argue the distinction between accepting and upvoting is anything but nuanced. You can accept an answer as a good enough workaround, even though it is not the perfect solution you want. Considering you will vote (up or down) for more often than you will accept answers, it seems sensible to not have a special case where, in that rare occurrence where you accept an answer, it would automatically upvote it as well.

Comment: So you vote up "perfect solutions", but you accept "good enough workarounds"? Yeah, I'd call that nuance. And I'd also bet that there are plenty of users who would use those two actions exactly the other way around. (Me, for instance - I generally upvote anything that is useful, and I accept an answer if it directly answers the question and either solves the problem or explains why there is no solution.)

Comment: You can do a hybrid approach. When accepting an answer, it could have a visible animation on upvote, making it clear they're distinct actions. If you really wanted to, you could only do this for new users, or for users who don't tend to upvote when they accept the answer-- or have a toast that pops up and says "answer automatically upvoted". The lack of new users upvoting accepted answers might demotivate people from answering questions for beginners.

Answer (score 61):

There's one corner case which hasn't been mentioned yet: you accept an answer, but you don't have any votes left for the day :)

Comment: Well then you could just uv it the next day, but people can be forgetful.

Comment: Yes, I guess I was more talking about why someone wouldn't "upvote and accept" at the same time.

Comment: There's another edge case, too.  What if you can't upvote because you don't have enough reputation?

Comment: Perhaps the daily vote limit shouldn't apply when you would like to upvote an answer that you have accepted.

Comment: This answers the first question in the OP. Do you have a stance on the second question?

Comment: @sancho.s: I don't have strong feelings either way, to be honest.

Comment: @SteveP., That's not the edge case, it's the [usual case](http://www.forbes.com/sites/quora/2013/01/03/is-it-common-for-new-programmers-to-be-intimidated-by-stack-overflow/).

Comment: @Pacerier The real question is why Forbes is mining Quora for content to repost.

Answer (score 47):

Accepting w/out upvoting makes sense in one situation IMHO.

If you end up using an answer that you don't like, but works.

The check should not also upvote.

Comment: Don't presume for the user.  You'd think the world would have learned after daytime running lights.

Comment: Could have run out of votes for the day...

Comment: Absolutely!!! If the user is annoying and/or abusive. Arrogant or otherwise acting in a way which you do not support. But the content is accurate. I want to mark it as corrrect, so that others who view my question will be able to find the correct answer, but I don't want to upvote this person behaviour.

Comment: So there might be an aditional tooltip stating "if this answer is correct and you like it, consider upvoting it as well" after the answer was accepted.

Comment: If the up-vote is automatic based on acceptance, then for those rare situations where you want to show the correct answer but not reward the user for other reasons, you could always un-do the up-vote manually (in other words, the up-vote would happen, the user would be told the up-vote happened, but it is not set in stone - though I'm not sure if SO would need to keep track of the auto-up-vote for the situation where the user later decided to un-accept that answer and accept a different answer - that's about the only technical limitation I foresee).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't think the situation is as rare as you might think.

Comment: @fredsbend ok, I don't we could state it either way with much authority.

Comment: I don't see why the *default* isn't to upvote upon accept. Users can always remove the upvote, or even downvote(!), if they feel the upvote is not appropriate.

Comment: @AaronBertrand However, such upvote should not get locked _ever_. No automatic action done this way in your name should be inundoable. Well, no automatic action should be done this way in your name :/ People, it's just rep, stupid number on some website, so relax :)

Comment: "_If you end up using an answer..._", then it's _useful_ (which is what an upvote means), right? Or are upvotes considered similar to likes (thumbs up) on social media?

Answer (score 29):

Following on from what VonC said.  I see a lot of occasional users who might accept an answer, but don't have the 15 rep required for an upvote.  Is this a special case where SO could apply the upvote when the answer is accepted?

Comment: It somehow feels wrong to me to not upvote an accepted answer. For my part, once I gained the privilege, I went back and upvoted the accepted answers, but many people either won't bother or may never even come back to the site again. The upvote shouldn't apply automatically, but I think users should start out with the privilege to upvote the accepted answer to their own questions.

Comment: @toxalot Perhaps, in the least users should be allowed to up and down vote on answers to their own questions regardless of rep. It is their question and if they think one answer is bunk and another is good but the community disagrees then the questioner's opinion should take precedence.

Answer (score 21):

There are badges available specifically for people who get a lot of their answers accepted with zero up-votes (Tenacious and Unsung Hero).

If the system were to change as suggested, to automatically give an up-vote to an answer you then accept those badges would have to change as well.

(This might not be a bad thing, as the current position does make winning those badges somewhat hit-and-miss, depending on the intelligence of the people you've tried to help.)

Comment: This could easily be changed to 'X accepted answers with zero upvotes [exclucing votes from the person who accepted]'.

Answer (score 14):

Accepting an answer without upvoting it rarely makes sense (and *never* in the case of my own answers, of course). 8-)} But I agree with others that it shouldn't be forced or automated; having the system cast an upvote on your behalf seems wrong.

So how about this:

If you accept an answer *and* you're able to upvote it, clicking the checkmark could produce a pop-up prompt that asks whether you want to upvote it as well. Add some *brief* wording indicating that it's not mandatory, but probably a good idea.

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes you get a number of answers, none of which quite hit the mark, but there is one that gets you 80% of the way to a solution. That's one reason for perhaps not awarding an upvote AND the correct answer.

The other reason is, [as Jon points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting/697#697), where you've run out of votes for the day.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe some people think that +15 that you already get for an accepted answer is enough and they want to save their upvotes for other questions/answers?  It's also possible that they're already out of votes for the day.

I personally don't think it makes any sense to accept an answer without upvoting it (upvote means "this was helpful", if it works and you're accepting it, it must have been helpful), but it's so easy to just click the other button I don't see any reason they should be combined into one atomic action.

Comment: IMHO The accept/no upvote almost always come from new users who aren't aware of the vote cap, never mind hitting it.

Answer (score 7):

Keep it separate. As Bill the Lizard pointed out, a lot of times users might think that "+15 is already enough". This is particularly true for the type of questions asked by new users (the ones most likely to not upvote when accepting an answer)... Pointing out for the millionth time that someone's not using the correct operators shouldn't entitle me to 25 points... In fact, the easiest questions are already the ones generating the most upvotes as everyone feels qualified to agree.

I feel that one of the structural weaknesses of SO is that the way that rep is awarded rewards users who cherry-pick easy questions and rely on the laziness of voters who will only bother voting for answers that they can validate in 10 seconds or less... Automatically awarding an additional +10 seems an unnecessary reward (at least this is my experience in the PHP/JS/CSS tags where there are lots of inexperienced users)... There are a lot of technically correct but uninspiring answers, and providing even higher rewards for answering large numbers of simple questions provides exactly the opposite incentive that we should be aiming for... Correct answers are rewarded well enough and can always be upvoted if the OP wants.

Answer (score 6):

I have several excellent reasons,

You can not upvote your own answer, leading to complications when a user answers their own question.

There are instances where the question might solve your answer, but does so in a low quality, or dirty (not best practice) manner that is not a good solution, although you do not mind using it yourself.

And finally, Nobody would be able to get the Neruto Hat then.

But seriously, as stated in other answers, it really is pretty easy to click the upvote button after accepting, so it wouldn't make much difference overall. While this was a great idea, I think it is not really worth the effort of the development team to implement.

Answer (score 5):

It never makes sense to accept without an upvote, but the functionality should remain separate. It is a good way to judge people who actually 'get it' and deserve your attention.

Comment: @jjnguy: Either the answer is helpful and correct or not. The only time your condition should be true is if the person is not using the system properly.

Comment: @jjnguy: Which is what my answer says. What are you arguing?

Comment: hehe, all i read was your first half sentence...my bad...

Comment: As mentioned by jjnguy's answer, there may be behaviour you DON'T want to endorse, but content that you do. So I'd mark the answer as correct, but they don't deserve an upvote.

Comment: Also, I'm downvoting you for an incorrect answer (-1)

Comment: @devinb: And as I discussed with jjnguy, if it answered your question and you accepted it, it is by definition helpful. Therefore it should be upvoted.

Comment: If I ask "How do I XYZ given that ABC" and someone says "you just GHI F_ckstar", well, they might be correct, but they aren't getting an upvote from me.

Comment: @devinb: Sounds like it was helpful to me. Whether it was the answer to accept or not is up for debate, but not an upvote.

Comment: @devinb: The system seems to be structured so that, ideally, someone with enough rep will come along and remove the needless insult.

Comment: @pesto: Absolutely. Once that happens, the answer will get an upvote from me. Until then, it is simply "Correct" and not "encouraged"

Comment: @devinb, The point is with the auto-upvote, a user with your knowledge will correctly undo the upvote, where as without auto-upvote, some user will never know (or got the chance to correct) they can upvote the answer that he/she just marked as answer...

Answer (score 4):

When asking questions, posting answers, voting (up/down), accepting, etc., we are participating of a community that helps us all.

What I personally value most is the **legacy** built by the community, which makes the system useful in the long term. An essential part of this is a rating system that reflects **usefulness**. I have benefited quite a lot from it.

I think that the focus on this usefulness for the SO community is often relegated, in favor of the reputation earned by users. Both go together, that is how SO works, but

> When a decision is to be made, **usefulness + legacy should prevail as a criterion**.

Following up with this rationale, if accepting goes naturally with upvoting in most of the cases, [something that proactively favors the upvoting in these cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_effect) would be most convenient.

Now, the due answer to the specific question: ***So would it not make sense to have the "Accept" button upvote the question too?***, I would say **YES, with an option for explicitly not upvoting**. But any other action favoring this will also be interesting.

Note that, by setting the default for an answer being accepted to “Upvote” (as opposed to “Not upvote”):

1. One is **not forcing the behavior** of the OP. One is only **[influencing the behavior of the OP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_effect)** in the direction it is overwhelmingly agreed that most often (not univocally) describes reality. This is contrary to what is stated in quite a few answers and comments.
2. One is selecting one of the two possible default actions. Setting the default to “Not upvote” is also influencing the behavior of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

When you've already upvoted an answer, but you come back later and realise that you also should have accepted it?  (I've done this.)

Comment: Heheh, true.. but that would still be both accepting the answer and voting it up

Comment: Except that if you aren't careful, you could allow people to 'upvote' a particular answer twice, which I'm pretty sure is against some form of local rule.

Comment: @Margaret, the system should know that you've already up-voted, regardless of whether the up-vote was automatic. Or else something is really wrong with the schema.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there ever a case where you would want to accept an answer, but not
>   upvote it?

Looking at the answers, comments, and votes on both, it seems most users here believe that when accepting an answer you are likely to upvote.

It may well be that in most scenarios, on some sites, the accepted answer is also worthy of an upvote from the question OP.
Some sites might have specific niches whereby an answer is either poor and worthy of nothing or  a downvote, or good answers worthy of both being accepted *and* an upvote from the question OP.

But this is simply not "*always*" the case on all sites, in all tags.

Maybe it was more true 6 years ago when this was asked? That is perfectly possible and acceptable :)

> So would it not make sense to have the "Accept" button upvote the
>   answer too?

No, because the two functions serve entirely different purposes, and I'd like to retain control over being able to accept and upvote separately based on the given scenario.

Paraphrasing from [another relevant answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/262061/230506) of mine:

1. I upvote because the answer was good, helpful, useful, informative,
   etc
2. I accept an answer when it answered my question, but it's not
   necessarily a "good" answer so I'm not necessarily also going to
   upvote

So there most certainly are scenarios where accepted and not upvoting is perfectly reasonable.

For example, in a "link only" answer, the information in the link's destination may well answer the question perfectly, so the OP can accept because "this answered their question".
But it being link only makes it a poor answer and so not worthy of an upvote.
(This is of course based on no other answers present, etc).

Or, perhaps more simply, the answer is just worthy of "accept" because it resolved my problem, but the answer author took no time or effort to explain when doing so could have been useful to me and others. Perhaps the grammar is bad, or the answer is generally lazy as if "here, I cannot be bothered, this will do you".
In which case I do not want to upvote, but accepting the answer is fair.

The point is, no matter how rare it may or may not be that we accept but *do not also* upvote, the fact there are scenarios where this happens means we should not automate it.

Answer (score 3):

Initially I thought this was a terrible idea, given how often I've seen answers that did, yes, solve the problem, but only barely and without much generality.

But the comments suggesting that the feature be limited only to *initially* upvoting (when possible), while still allowing an immediate undoing of this when desired, changed my mind.

Given that provision, there really is no technical reason it couldn't work well. If someone is out of votes for the day or doesn't have the rep to upvote? *You just don't add the vote*, simplicity itself. If someone doesn't really like the answer *that* much? Just undo the vote; the button will even change colors conveniently to alert you.

There are two remaining social considerations that I can see. The first is the expectation that would develop that an accept should also mean an upvote, potentially leading to drama in cases where that doesn't happen. Well, except that that expectation already strongly exists, so I don't see that changing much.

The second is a systemic shifting of careless accepters a little further toward upvotes than is presently the case, even for answers that are borderline. I'm not really sure this is a very serious problem, and arguably it's even part of the intention. (Especially for new users that just gained upvote privileges recently and aren't entirely aware of how things work.)

Given all this, it really seems like a reasonable feature to streamline things, especially if, the first time it triggers on a given account, a popup appears to explain what just happened.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of answer I intentionally accpected but did not upvote:

https://serverfault.com/a/744471/328195

Why? The answer was good because it worked and answered the question...but  I decided it did not deserve an upvote because it was rude and almost offensive (it has been edited since by a more clever person who removed the rude part of the answer, see the revision: https://serverfault.com/posts/744471/revisions).

Comment: So you know and you know how to undo. This is about new users who don't know the difference between them.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Sure, but the OP did not mention the question only for new users, he asked "Is there ever a case where you would want to accept an answer, but not upvote it?"

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have read the answers and some of the comments talking about some exceptional cases but the **main reason** I think is that up-voting take *15 reputations*. In some of the cases questions are asked by new user having just *1 reputations*. So, even if they up-vote it won't show up.

However, this is where **Stack Overflow** comes to the party with a ***gold badge*** for such users.

> **Unsung Hero:** Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

I myself have this gold badge. I think this is somehow good not letting users having less than 15 reputations to up-vote, otherwise they will keep up-voting their own answers with different accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes get two answers that are really close to each other in quality, and would like to accept both (but can't) — so what I'll do is:

- accept what I feel is the better answer, but *not* upvote it
- give the runner-up answer my upvote

I consider this to be a little more "fair" to the 2nd-place answerer, who gets 10 points from me. The accepted answerer is getting 15 points + the prestige of having the accepted answer.

Comment: If they're both good answers, upvote both.

Comment: that's not the point, the point is that I can't accept both. If I could accept both or couldn't accept either, I'd upvote both.

Comment: So in that scenario you would upvote and accept both, even though you thought one was clearly a better answer?  I agree with devinb

Answer (score 1):

It could be that though the answer was helpful, it was not at all well written.

There are several things that contribute to having a well written answer, including the way of explanation. Maybe the answer just gave a small tip that helped you reach a solution yourself, but the answer itself was not the solution. Maybe the answer misunderstood the question and gave a partially irrelevant explanation, that however helped you find your Eureka point. Maybe the answer has uncorrected mistakes indicated in the comments but are not fixed by the answerer.

In such cases, you might want to pin the answer so that others who open the question read it, but you don't think the answer itself deserves an upvote. Well, surely the op could help edit the answer or self answer his question from the new information, but not everyone may be willing to spend so much time on stack exchange, especially after they've already got the answer for themselves.

Answer (score -2):

I have previously not upvoted an answer that I accepted. I did that because the person who provided the answer did so in a comment, and SO won't allow you to accept a comment as a best answer, so I had to make a new answer myself that was basically just a copy of what he had said. It didn't feel right to upvote myself, especially when I wasn't the one who had come up with the answer.

The obvious solution here, I think, is to have the system automatically upvote when you accept, but also allow you to remove that upvote after acceptance.

Comment: You can't vote on your own posts in any event.

Comment: I didn't know that. It's good that you can't. However, my overall point is still valid - there are cases where the person who provided the accepted solution is not the one who deserves the praise (in the form of upvotes) for coming up with it.