# When you accept an answer should you also vote it up?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

By accepting an answer you're obviously already saying that it was useful. Should an additional up-vote be reserved for answers that are particularly useful, or do people always tend to use the two in unison (or the contrary)?

Comment: This would be more appropriate as a community-wiki question.

Comment: Glad to see other Owen's floating around out there.

Comment: Indeed! Though we're so sparse that can feel claustrophobic when other Owens are in the vicinity.

Comment: Agreed!  Maybe we can work out a split.  I'll take Java, Python, and Ruby on Rails.  You take C++, C#, and bash scripting.  You can have Stackoverflow Monday through Friday and I'll take it on the weekends?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I usually use the two together because if I accept it, it's a good answer, but there might be a better one that I accept an hour, day, or week later.

Comment: Yes I do this too. Always helps to see those big numbers.

Answer (score 34):

I usually vote up all answers to my question unless specifically unhelpful or plain incorrect. They took the time to reply and contributed. I usually pick an answer a while later, maybe after testing it.

I guess this means that I usually do both.

Comment: I do this as well, for the same reasons.

Comment: Even duplicates? If they're duplicates at around the same time then I can see doing that, but if someone repeats an existing answer more than five or ten minutes after the original was posted, I'd say the duplicate doesn't deserve a vote.

Comment: i was doing that as a courtesy, but realized that if i do the question falls off of the unanswered list immediately, which reduces its exposure - so now i wait until the answers have settled down and then do it

Comment: Yeah, that's the pattern for subjective questions like this one. For technical questions where I need a question I do tend to leave voting up until I've checked for that reason.

Answer (score 18):

I upvote any answers that are helpful: perhaps they're not the *exact* solution, but they're alternatives, or on the right path.

Sometimes there are duplicates. If duplicate answers should be 'accepted', I prefer them to be upvoted to match each other, or allow one answerer to retract his answer in favor of the other guy.

But overall, if you're accepting something you're *not* upvoting, why are you accepting it?

Comment: I agree; I just thought in some cases doing both might be overkill and wanted to hear people's input.

Answer (score 11):

Why not make the Accept function automatically give 1 upvote?  To me, it doesn't make sense to accept an answer without upvoting it.

Comment: @Mikey: I can imagine situations where you only got one answer, it was not great, but it gave you a pointer on how to solve the problem. So you could accept it, but not give it an upvote because it was not that great.

Comment: @warren: Well, of course not. What I meant: What should happen if accepting gives an automatic upvote, but you're out of votes for the day?

Comment: @Justin: I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt - pretty sure that @Justin means you could always vote the answer up tomorrow if you ran out of votes today.

Comment: @warren: Hmm, OK, then Justin misunderstood me, too.

Comment: @Hendrik - I did. I see what you mean now. Good point.

Comment: @Mike, It has been requested before but declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/686/159916

Comment: @HendrikVogt, It's easy to have an accept gives +25 rep instead of +15 and you can't manually upvote what you have already accepted , then the vote limit doesn't matter. (If you had upvoted previously before you accepted, then that upvote is refunded if the upvote had been done on that day)

Answer (score 4):

I upvote and accept.

Answer (score 3):

I only upvote if the answer is **both** correct and well formulated.

Comment: This describes the use of a feature but doesn't really answer the question of whether both features should be used together.

Answer (score 2):

The answer that is accepted by the user solves the user problem. Meaning they should have either tested it or it solved their problem. If the question is going to accepted by the user it should be up voted by the user.

Upvote any answers that helps add to the knowledge of the question, they may not have the perfect answer *per se* but help on the path of the perfect answer.

Comment: This describes the use of the two features but doesn't really answer the question of whether they should be used together.