# Picking Right Answer vs Up Vote

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Accepting answer without upvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting)
>   [When you accept an answer should you also vote it up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/when-you-accept-an-answer-should-you-also-vote-it-up)

If you ask a question and then pick a right answer, should you also up vote that answer? 
Can a question be "right" but not worth an up vote?

Comment: duplicate.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/when-you-accept-an-answer-should-you-also-vote-it-up/

Comment: also a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting

Answer (score 0):

To quote my previous [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/when-you-accept-an-answer-should-you-also-vote-it-up/13393#13393)

> I upvote any answers that are helpful: perhaps they're not the exact solution, but they're alternatives, or on the right path.
>
> Sometimes there are duplicates. If duplicate answers should be 'accepted', I prefer them to be upvoted to match each other, or allow one answerer to retract his answer in favor of the other guy.
>
> But overall, if you're accepting something you're not upvoting, why are you accepting it?