# Is it possible to make a question CW but not its answers?

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

Is it possible to make a question Community Wiki to avoid the appearance of, and discussions about, rep-gathering (especially when it's a "easy" question likely to get many upvotes) but not the answers, because it is a regular question and not a CW one?

> **Disclaimer:** I am of course asking this for a serious question over on SO, and not for any of these possible MSE questions that would turn out to be instant favourites with the community, and net a ton of upvotes:
>
> - What is your favourite [**Unicorn Avatar**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)?
> - What does your [**unicorn avatar**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) look like?
> - Why do *you* think [**unicorn avatars**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) are so popular?
> - How do you like your [**unicorn avatar**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)?
> - (Added for @quack) How do you like Pekka's alternative E-Mail [**unicorn avatar**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns)?
>
>   [image]

Comment: Not really, no. When you make the question CW, all the answers after that will automatically be CW. If a moderator makes the questions CW, all answers, even the ones given before the question became CW, will also become CW.

Comment: +1 Pekka: I think that is a great idea. Unfortunate, though...

Comment: @dboarman cheers. Unfortunate why?

Comment: _*loads shotgun*_  someone mention unicorns?  :)

Comment: @Pekka: ...unfortunate that it's an all or nothing on CW. An alternative *mode* for asking questions considered easy, basic, common knowledge, etc. would diminish gains from up-votes. While the questions may be *basic* to most of us, there are going to be members who don't understand the purpose of static classes, patterns, etc. As a self-taught, above average hobby developer, these are some of the *building blocks* I miss out on (esp. patterns). *C# Unleashed* just does not cover some things in detail. So you turn to the Internet to start filling in gaps.  :)

Comment: @quack I added one for you! :) @dboarman Good point. The question I have in mind is actually kind of a PHP security reference, which exists in the form of dozens of separate questions but not as a "compendium". I'm ready to chip in a 550 bounty to get it started but need to get it through the first 24 hours alive :) Which is why I'm asking. I wouldn't want to make it CW because it would take away incentive to answer. Rep whoring is a non-issue anyway really, because if you're somewhat active on SO, you'll hit the rep cap either way.

Comment: See also the feature request "Option to not gain rep for votes on a question, but still have answers gain rep." at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41220/option-to-not-gain-rep-for-votes-on-a-question-but-still-have-answers-gain-rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be possible, but evidently no longer is.  Sorry about posting an incorrect answer earlier, and thanks to everyone who jumped in to correct me.

<strike>Yes.  When you make a question CW, all of the answers are CW *by default*.  Each person can still manually uncheck the CW box on their answer before posting.</strike>

If you're trying to avoid the appearance of rep whoring, but you think the question is still valid (maybe for a question you intend to answer yourself, or whatever reason), I don't think it would be out of line to put a note at the end of the question pointing out the CW state of the question and reminding people to make their answers non-CW.

Comment: Cheers @Bill, didn't know that! And good advice.

Comment: @Bill: are you sure? It *used* to work that way, but I haven't seen the CW checkbox when composing a new answer to a CW question in *ages*...

Comment: **No, this does NOT work.  Answers posted to CW questions do not have the option box for CW or not.**

Comment: You can test this by posting an answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13390/when-you-accept-an-answer-should-you-also-vote-it-up

Comment: Or post to this SO wiki question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713232/problem-with-png-image-on-top-of-an-image-in-css

Comment: @Pollyanna Awww. That's too bad! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Seven up votes for an incorrect answer.  This voting thing works.  **NOT!**

Comment: @Pollyanna In the spirit of leaving correctly answered questions for future generations, can you post an answer saying "no"? I'll switch the accept if I still can.

Comment: @raven is right on this one.  You can downvote me when I'm wrong folks. ;)

Comment: @Bill: yet nobody does.  **High rep users can do no wrong, now can they?**  (Lest anyone not get it, I'm just playing Devil's advocate here.  I have nothing but respect for Bill.)

Comment: @pekka - Shogs got you covered in the other answer, thanks though.

Comment: @raven - eh, I don't downvote.

Comment: @Pollyanna: I like that attitude, and I am trying to adopt it, but haven't quite got the hang of it yet.

Comment: @Pollyanna: I'll take comments explaining why I'm wrong over downvotes any day.  Both together is fine, but downvotes alone would have definitely left me scratching my head, particularly in this case when I know I *used to be* right.

Comment: @raven @bill - I'm not convinced that never downvoting is the right thing to do.  Mostly I leave negative comments and let others do the dirty work so I don't have to sully my hands...  ;-D