# Option to not gain rep for votes on a question, but still have answers gain rep

Tags: feature-request, reputation, questions, community-wiki

I have been accused of asking many questions [solely to gain rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89989/crazyjugglerdrummer). However, they were all genuine, and I don't want to have me or my questions looked down on for this reason. I would be fine if I didn't gain rep for these questions (and if I lost all the rep for them I've already gained on them).

However, making them community wiki would cause the wonderful people who answered them to lose the rep they deserved. Would it be possible for them to gain rep but not me?

related: [Please charge rep for questions after threshold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold)

Comment: @ear: it's `you're`. `your` means "belonging to you".

Comment: I usually don't correct that because it is on of the few mis-contractions that I think is acceptable. lol

Comment: Ah, I had no idea you were that young. This casts a new light on that Python question.

Comment: @CrazyJuggler: you should tag this *[feature-request]* if that's your intention here.  otherwise it's seen as just a *[discussion]*.

Comment: See also "Is it possible to make a question CW but not its answers?" at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39351/is-it-possible-to-make-a-question-cw-but-not-its-answers

Answer (score 5):

Your profile looks perfectly acceptable to me.

> 51 questions 
>   167 answers
>
> 4281 rep
>
> 10 questions with zero votes 
> 1
>   question with negative votes.

Every other question you've asked has gotten upvotes.  Some of them have gotten lots of upvotes.  Which means you are asking good questions.

*Bask in the glory.*

Comment: Compare to http://stackoverflow.com/users/104015/shore ...3446 rep, 426 questions, 1 answer, 11 upvotes, 11 downvotes. Yikes.

Answer (score 3):

I very much agree with this.  One of the reasons I stopped posting "getting started guide" poll questions, such as [this git question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide), was because of the backlash from people who thought I was rep-whoring - the main reason to keep it non-cw is so people have a good reason to do a good job on the answers.

I think there's a lot of value in having a single quick start guide for SO, and it's terrifically easy to crowd source such a guide here.

Way too much flack, though, for something that obviously (by votes and favorites) benefits so many.

So yes, please let me CW my question without CW'ing the answers!  That should at least reduce the wiki-bullying a little.