# Asking upvote for accepted answer

Tags: discussion, voting, accepted-answer

Some times people accept the answer but don't upvote it. When this happens to me I'm always tempted to ask them to upvote it, but I don't know if I'll look rude or needy lol. Should we ask for upvote when our answer is accepted or just let it go?

(It just happened to me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401105/one-resource-dictionary-for-all-projects-in-a-solution/1407401#1407401))

Comment: That isn't half as frustrating as answering the question and all you get in return is a comment saying "thanks, you fixed my problem" without either an "accept" or an upvote.

Comment: Hahaha, that is true!

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: I'd say it's about 3/5 more annoying.

Comment: _Very_ related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting This question might be a duplicate

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, and here is why.

If you were correct and that answer solved the OP's problem, that is what the rep from the accepted answer is for.

An upvote rates the quality, usefulness, etc. of the answer.  It can still be the correct answer and still be a crappy answer/solution, hence no upvotes or many people responding to it.

Of course, there are always exceptions, but not a good idea in general to rep beg.
Please See: [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19522#19522)

Answer (score 6):

I'm sorry, but you should have picked a better example question.  That particular one doesn't deserve an upvote even if it is the only answer.  In fact, it could be the poster child for an accepted answer that doesn't deserve an upvote.

Comment: I've seen answers worse than that get an upvote (just link, no text at all)

Comment: Not from me.  If you want an upvote, I'd say the minimum would be a link with a summary of (or quote from) the relevant portion of the linked site.

Comment: So, are you saying if it had all that (a link with a summary of (or quote from) the relevant portion of the linked site), one can ask for an upvote?

Comment: Probably better examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401275/1401319#1401319 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402428/1402458#1402458

Comment: And I don't think this answer deserves upvotes either because it is out of context, and you already have 3.

Comment: @Jon: That first one would make me cry.  That guy specifically *asked* for you and didn't upvote your answer.

Answer (score 3):

What would an upvote accomplish except to gain more rep. Being the correct answer will already place your answer at the top.  You also get 15 rep (5 more points than an upvote) as well.

Assigning something as an answer seems to accomplish a lot and asking / adding yet another vote from the user that just assigned your answer as the correct answer and awarding you rep seems to be just saying an answer should be worth 25 rep instead of 15.

Answer (score 2):

I say just let it go.  I don't think we'd need the extra noise on SO, SF, etc.

Comment: Are your 'No Velociraptors' avatar and my ammonite avatar going to have to duke it out?

Comment: lol bring it on!

Answer (score 2):

I must admit I've done it in the past, but most of the time I will let it slide. You would be right in saying that asking for an upvote would come across as being needy.

Comment: Would you like an upvote on this answer?  All you have to do is ask...

Comment: I asked the person who accepted his answer on the link he provided to upvote his answer.  Maybe I'm codependant or something.

Comment: lol thanks, maybe that's the way to go actually

Answer (score 2):

I dislike the rep begging thing (it happens on too many sites) - but I do think that an accepted answer should be treated the same as an upvote for tag badge purposes, so that if your answer is accepted then it counts as one vote towards the tag badges.

If you answer a question set by a low-rep user they have no way of upvoting except by accepting and too few people seem to bother upvoting generally any more.