# Should accepting an answer automatically up-vote it?

Tags: feature-request, voting, accepted-answer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accepting answer without upvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting)

Lately a lot of my accepted answers have 0 upvotes. Out of my last 8 accepted answers 5 are without upvotes.

I think that in 90% of the cases it's because the OP doesn't know that they could (should?) upvote. I'd feel bad explaining to the new users that they could also upvote me... in the end it's no big deal but still.

**So what about either an auto-upvote when accepting or at least a message saying "you know that upvoting the answer would be nice ?".**

I know it has been [discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting), but the accepted answer states:

> Since it is simple enough to cast an
>   upvote and accept the answer, I don't
>   a see a reason to constrain the user
>   in this manner. I agree, **I've never
>   had a situation where I wasn't
>   upvoting along with accepting**. But,
>   everyone has a different
>   reason/rationale for upvoting, so I
>   don't think the system should force
>   that upvote.

... and I don't agree, there are lots of cases where users don't upvote when accepting, simply because they don't know.

Comment: You should add an answer to the existing question in stead of creating a new one.

Comment: You might want to reword the title to more closely match the body of the question. Something like "Should accepting an answer automatically up-vote it?" Oh and what @fretje said too.

Comment: Am trying to think of a scenario that the OP not wanting to upvote an answer he/she accepted. I can't.

Comment: @o.k.w: because *you* can't doesn't mean other people can't.

Comment: @chrisF fixed, sorry about that sometime my english is sketchy

Comment: @fretje it's not really an answer, and the other question has been asked a year ago, so I guess it's a closed topic and other answers might not be relevant anymore.

Comment: @marcgg - don't apologise for your English. It was just in this case I read the title as implying that accepting an answer **did** up-vote it as well, so I was expecting a bug report or discussion of a new feature.

Comment: Here at meta, as long as a question is not closed or doesn't have a status-* tag, it is *not* a "closed topic".

Comment: Sorry, I only see now that you classified this as a "feature request", and with the title change it might indeed not be a dupe then. I still don't agree though. You should never be "forced" to give an upvote.

Comment: @fretje yeah but the first question wasn't a feature-request... so it's not going to be status-something any time soon. I would have edited it, but I don't have the rep

Answer (score 5):

Check the rep on those users -- are they below 15? More importantly, were they when your answers were marked as best? "New" users -- that is, users who are below 15 rep -- can't vote, even on their own questions. Likely they *wanted* to upvote you (they figured out the system enough to mark an answer, after all), but they were simply not allowed to.

A quick glance at your [SO profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90691/marcgg)'s lowest-voted answers seems to indicate that these are in fact very low-rep users. I have no problem believing that a [user who now has 351 rep was below 15 on February 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265408/jquery-dynamic-events-how-to-achieve/2265436#2265436), for example.

Certainly a [user who currently has 23 rep was probably under 15 4 hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340550/how-to-use-hudson-tracker-with-a-ruby-on-rails-project/2340606#2340606). :)

[This guy *currently* has under 15 rep.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340975/query-with-ruby-on-rails/2341003#2341003)

(Note all times and reps are as of this posting. I have *no* intention of keeping them current. YMMV.)

Comment: Oh... I thought that users bellow 15rep could upvote on their questions! Why can't they, was that discussed before?

Comment: @macrgg - they can't because it could to lead to rep farming where a new sock puppet account asks lots of simple questions which are answered by the real account. The sock puppet then upvotes all of these - rep gain 10x number of questions.

Comment: I think they did not upvote because they didn't know of its affect/importance. IMO - it is a small flaw that an accepted answer can get either 15 or 25 points depending on whether the OP chose to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

### **No**

Please no. You are able to accept *and* up-vote (if you meet the requirement of having 15 rep), so I see no reason to force it upon anyone.

If something like this would be implemented, I still would like to be able to take the up-vote back without taking the accept back. Some answers deserve to be "accepted", but that doesn't mean they automatically deserve 25 rep from one user!

Comment: In what case you'd accept an answer and not upvote it?

Comment: @marcgg: if it was correct, or led me to the correct answer, but was otherwise an atrocious answer.  or, on meta, i disagreed with it, even if it was correct (in which case i'd likely *downvote* it).  or, y'know, if i'd generally been having a rotten day and didn't feel like it.

Comment: @quack meta is a different story. I can get accepting but not upvoting on meta, but SO and co it's a different story. If the answer is correct, I'd say it's a bit rude to not give the user credit just because you didn't felt like it :\

Comment: @marcgg: Like already stated: when I think an answer is "acceptable", but it doesn't deserve 25 rep from one user. This *is* something extremely subjective though.

Comment: @marcgg: You *are* already giving credit by "accepting" (+15 is even more than upvoting), so you're not rude at all!

Comment: @fretje: Wouldn't you feel like "wtf?" if some user would accept but not upvote? If the answer is badly formated, they should add a comment asking to improve the answer or something. And not upvoting just because of your current mood is not the best way to go, imho

Comment: @marcgg: No I wouldn't. As I said, this is extremely subjective. I don't see the merit in discussing it, let alone making it a default.

Comment: It would also be inconsistent: when you accept *your own* answer, it wouldn't be up-voted (you can't up-vote your own answers).