# Is there a reason an asker would downvote an answer, but then mark it as accepted?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes, accepted-answer

This is not a duplicate of [Why may I accept and downvote the same answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42817/why-may-i-accept-and-downvote-the-same-answer]), as that is about why the feature hasn't been locked out or removed.

**I'm asking if there's any possible reason that someone who asks a question would downvote an answer, then accept it.**  Assume that this someone is serious about their decision and won't change their mind later.

Comment: Maybe it's the correct answer, but unwelcome none the less? If you went to the doctor and he told you that you had a serious illness, you'd hardly think to challenge his diagnosis, but that doesn't mean you *liked* it.

Comment: Perhaps one might accept an answer that is technically correct and solves the problem, but also downvote it for being unnecessarily rude and condescending.

Comment: @ff524 Ooh, that's a good one, never thought of that.

Comment: OP may think the answer isn't good (not detailed enough, badly written whatever) but it did help them (got a hint in the right direction).

Comment: @Oded In that scenario, I'd imagine the converse of Jesse's pattern: the OP would upvote (as [partially] helpful), but not accept (as a complete answer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many reasons. I will list them here:

- Trying to earn a badge like Critic and Civic Duty
- The answer was originally downvoted long ago but was then accepted as the OP finally understood the answer and marked it as best but couldn't remove downvote due to grace period
- The OP is being a troll
- It was an accident to downvote in the first place
- It was to gain rep from the accept (just 1 more rep!)
- It was accident to accept the answer
- The answer was from Jon Skeet/ hacked by unicorns
- The answer was offensive
- The answer was in terrible quality but still led the OP to the solution
- Any other reason I can't think of that exists

Comment: There is a chance though... I did that once