# Disallow Questioner from Upvoting an Answer that she Accepted

Tags: bug, status-declined, answers, voting, accepted-answer

To avoid the sort of debate found on [a related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting), I think it's unneeded to allow one to upvote an Answer she Accepted.

Accepting an Answer pretty much implies an Upvote. So it's just extra work since a lot of people on that debate Upvote AND Accept, and you can find other varieties on that linked Question.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the debate in that question?

Comment: debate: Should I or should I not upvote?

Comment: @Tshepang what's wrong with that debate? I don't see the point

Comment: @Pekka, I added some info on the Question.

Comment: @Tshepang I still disagree. There can be situations when I don't like an answer but have to accept its truth (e.g. somebody saying "no, it's not possible".) Then there can be situations where I want to upvote the answer. No, I don't really see merit in this

Comment: @Pekka, seems like a petty distinction to me.

Comment: With >325 of them I'm all for it.  But it is a dupe and you didn't add any compelling arguments to the existing discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This clearly is a bad idea (according to the downvotes). I'm kinda convinced by [Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112/rejoice-rejoice-kbd-is-back):

> I still disagree. There can be situations when I don't like an answer but have to accept its truth (e.g. somebody saying "no, it's not possible".) Then there can be situations where I want to upvote the answer.

Comment: Sounds Pekka is not using votes as intended. It doesn't matter whether he "likes" the answer or not; if it a factually correct and well-presented answer, it deserves an upvote.

Comment: Imagine an Answer that just says ""no, it's not possible" without expanding on why. It's correct, but could be much better.

Comment: Right, that example is only half-useful, so it doesn't deserve an upvote. But that's an objective value judgement, not just a "I don't like it" :)

Answer (score 6):

Terrible idea. If anything, you should recommend it.