# Inform new users if they can upvote an answer they accepted

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, new-users, up-votes, popups

I surprisingly often stumble upon answers which were accepted but clearly not upvoted by the asker. For example, the answer has not received any upvotes at all or the asker’s vote count is zero. While I acknowledge that [this may be intentional in some cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68104/255554), most such cases happen with new users, who have only recently received the privilege to vote and who upvote after a friendly reminder.

Given the anonymity of votes and that I do not check the asker’s profile for every question with an accepted answer I stumbled upon, I assume that there is a huge dark figure for this phenomenon. Also, I naturally most often spot this on my own answers, which makes reminding the asker of their privileges somewhat awkward.

I thus propose that users which accept an answer are reminded by a pop-up that they can upvote it, if:

- They haven’t already upvoted it.
- They have the reputation required for voting.
- They have cast less than a handful of votes.

I consider the latter criterion to be better than an upper reputation for which the message is displayed, since I know at least one user with several thousand reputation points, who has cast much less upvotes or votes on answers than he has accepted answers on some sites (not that his acceptance rate or general feedback on answers is spectacular).