# Possible solution for (accidentally) not upvoting accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, reputation, voting, accepted-answer, up-votes

I have searched the site and found there is already a question about this: [*Accepting answer without upvoting?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/686/151832) but it is already 4 years old.

In my opinion, Auto-upvote should be in place and here is the full solution, does anyone know why this is still not in place? :P

***Improve even without Auto-Upvoting:***

1. For new users (thanks to [@psubsee2003](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196783/151832)) (rep. less than *** or never upvoted..) Highlight the upvote function and show tips like "you can upvote the
   answer if you think it's helpful" upon user accepting an answer.
2. Send reminder to user without enough Rep/vote, to upvote an already
   accepted answer, when they get enough Rep/vote.

*Possible problems with Auto-Upvoting:*

1. User don't have enough Rep to upvote
2. User don't have any vote left
3. User don't really want to upvote

*Solutions:*

1. Auto upvote the question that is accepted when they do get enough
   Rep. and send them a notice asking if they want to undo the upvote.
2. Auto upvote the question next day, and send them a notice asking if
   they want to undo.
3. Highlight the upvote and user can undo it upon marking as accepted.
   (this is not a problem compared with how user will never know they
   can upvote&accepted).

Comment: Why should an accept also cause an upvote? You get 15 rep...why does that need to be 25?

Comment: "does anyone know why this is still not in place?" - because no one implemented it?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/10/28/53298.aspx

Comment: @Bart, you answer already been marked as accepted, why do you need 15 rep then :)

Comment: I can accept an answer without upvoting it. That is a feature for me. Please don't take it away.

Comment: Your "undo the upvote" features would have to bypass the vote-locking system (votes are locked after 5 minutes until the post is edited). I'm not sure this is a good idea, as it would reopen a whole can of possible abuse.

Comment: @juergend, have you fully read my post, the point is you can and you know how to undo a upvote (in rarely cases), this is a suggestion for the system to help those do need some help/reminders.

Comment: The bigger problem is useful or upvoted answers NOT being accepted, since an accepted answer gives you more points.

Comment: @Oded, so are you saying, there is an approved solution, but not get implemented yet?

Comment: It's status-declined; there is no approved solution and one won't be developed unless the developers change their mind.

Comment: @Wooble, that's right, and this is my effort to try to change their mind..

Comment: And to all the down-voters, please do not down-vote purely because you don't agree with my suggestion, please read the tooltip of the down-vote button: `"this question does not show any research effort, it's unclear or not useful"` before clicking.

Comment: @Bolu: the tooltip doesn't accurately reflect how voting works on meta, unless you take "not useful" to mean "the feature you're requesting wouldn't be useful." [Changing the tooltip is also status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75049/change-upvote-downvote-tooltip-on-meta-sites)

Comment: @Bolu please learn that voting on [meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  Upvoting/Downvoting posts that are proposing features or changes to the way the system work is the community's way of expressing agreement or disagreement with the post.

Comment: @Bolu People can downvote for any reason that they want to.  Telling people not to downvote you isn't particularly constructive.  It can neither stop them, nor does it encourage them not to do so.  Telling people that they can't do something they know they very well can do is just going to make them that much less sympathetic to your case.

Comment: @Servy, agree, as long as they are not down-voting because they think this is a duplicated question, I can live with it.

Comment: @Bolu But it *is* a duplicate suggestion, and they *do* have every right to downvote for that reason if they want to .

Comment: @psubsee2003, thanks for enlighten me, that's fine then

Comment: @Servy, I do think I made more than duplicated suggestion, but anyway.

Comment: @Wooble, that suggestion gets +113 and still status-declined, no hope there then..... :(

Comment: Wow. That's one way to interpret what I said. But status-declined are also things that will not be implemented. In particular, solutions to non-existing problems will not get implemented.

Comment: @Oded, instead of `non-existing` problems, I would rather say `minor` problems or problems `haven't been recognized enough yet`.

Comment: @Bolu - or one could say, things perceived as problems by a small number of people and as non-issues by everyone else.

Comment: @Oded, is there a poll for this (e.g. do we need to improve the system to prevent accepted answer been accidentally left as non-upvoted?), or are you just drawing your conclusion based on tiny samples (95 viewers)? As even the other question I mentioned in my question got +74 upvotes (2521 viewers).

Comment: Statistics on (accepted + not upvoted) answers would shed light on this topic.

Comment: It is remarkable how the proposal in [Accepting answer without upvoting?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting) is so much upvoted (and it appears to be on the rise), and this one is getting downvoted. The two are different, of course, but is this a [bandwagon effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwagon_effect)?

Answer (score 5):

Upvotes and Accepted Answers mean 2 different things.  Why does one have to automatically mean the other.

Upvoting means "This answer is useful"

An accepted answer means "This is the best answer"

It is probably a rare occurrence, but what if an answer is the "best answer" but not helpful as the voter/OP chooses to define helpful.  The definition of when to upvote/downvote is intentionally left vague and the burden of deciding what a vote means has been left to each individual user.

So by forcing an upvote when they accept an answer, you are in fact telling the OP what his/her vote means, and there are plenty in the community who will not like that (including myself - for the record, I usually upvote answers I accept, but because I think they are worth the upvote, not because I have to upvote).

Just because I can undo the automatic upvote doesn't mean that I will remember.  What if I forget and my vote becomes locked in?  Now I have to edit to undo my vote.

And the suggestion of auto-upvoting the next day or in the future when the poster has the necessary privileges to do so, or because I used up my votes - now I have to remember to go back and undo the posts I don't want to upvote.  A notification in the Super-Collider Multi Dropdown is not going to be helpful for some very heavy users as they will get enough notifications that a reminder to un-upvote a post could get missed.

Basically, it seems like you are trying to "improve" an experience by forcing a behavior on everyone (and making their experience more complicated) just to teach new users that they can upvote.  Frankly, I think a badge or one of the reminders/notices you suggested would serve this purpose just as well without forcing something on everyone else.

Comment: Thank you, so my second suggestion is good :)

Comment: @Bolu only for new users... don't do it for everyone.

Comment: Edited in my suggestion

Comment: An accepted answer does not necessarily mean "This is the best answer", very often its not even a good answer, it just happens to be the answer that the OP chose for the OP's particular use case.

Comment: @apaul34208 the terminology I chose to use is taken directly from the tool tips so it wasn't skewed by my personal opinion.  I happen to agree with you, especially with new users.  I've seen a lot of answers where the OP continues talking in the comments about needing a solution when they've already accepted an answer

Comment: "Click to set this answer as your accepted answer; click again to toggle" and "The question owner accepted this as the best answer N hours ago" its a subtle difference, perhaps more emphasis should be placed on the fact that it is merely the OP's opinion

Comment: Something more like "The question owner accepted this answer N hours ago"

Answer (score -3):

Possible problems with upvoting?

That not because Stackexchange don't want people to upvotes answers, its just to prevent spam! Any user can account and upvote an answer or keep upvoting other answers without any limit!

And also, why would system auto upvote?

In help of this site, and at stackexchange its clearly told that: "Upvotes are used to show that these questions contain content that is helpfull" and the Mark As Answers differ from Upvotes because Mark as answer means that this answer worked for the post owner. So, this way upvotes and mark as answer differ in a lot manners!

Ok, the suggestions will be something like: You give me loan, I will notify you tomorrow to get it back if you want!

That's something like you are asking Stackoverflow to provide the user will a facility to give or get loans from users. that's even not allowed :D However, I do like that one! :) To allow the users some cookie to have and pay for it when they have some. But when the user gets 15 points, do he really need to get 10+?

And the second thing of yours, to let the user Upvote on his questions once he gets enough rep, That's the thing! I like that one. But Stackoverflow lacks it. Your future-request tag will be helpfull buddy.

Comment: So what about reminders that I've mentioned in my suggestions?

Comment: They are not better suggestions I guess..

Comment: The second suggestion is good! I read it now..

Comment: still -9 at it stands... :(

Comment: But buddy guess what? If its for me, I would really want you to get a chance of being the one to fight for this! :D I love the second option to get notified! I am gonna +1 your question :)

Comment: Thanks for your encouragement, I'm about to go though :)

Comment: Yeah you should, and don't worry about the downvotes, its just the way it goes through! :D Have a look on my answer, go to my profile and see! Just downvotes.

Comment: LOL, you should earn a badge for that...

Comment: Man, stackoverflow should provide me a new website for that! :D even medal :D