# What is the logic behind allowing an answer to be accepted, but not upvoted?

Tags: discussion, answers, voting, accepted-answer

On the lower traffic SEs I frequent, it seems that occasionally an asker will accept an answer without upvoting it.  I am wondering if this is intentionally allowed (on the site's part) for a specific reason.  Something about seeing a question with no upvotes, a single answer with no upvotes and an accepted flag rankles me.

It seems like accepting an answer should automagically upvote it once, but I may be missing a reason for that not being the case.

Comment: What about users who don't have enough rep to upvote an answer?

Comment: See [linked discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting) - also note that every asker has the ability to accept an answer, but must *earn* the privilege of voting; many do not.

Comment: Thanks.  I am embarrassed my poorly worded search did not return that result.  The low rep user is the situation that perfectly explains it.