# Improving an answer by editing or by re-answering

Tags: discussion, etiquette

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Editing versus Answering?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15839/editing-versus-answering)

I was contemplating about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/wpf-textbox-how-to-define-some-restriction/7572924#7572924). The answer is mostly correct, but it misses some cases and I am not 100% sure if the author missed them on purpose.

I've edited the code to handle the additional cases but wasn't sure if to suggest an edit or to submit as a new answer with reference to original author. The new code is about 25% longer than the original answer.

What should I have done? Suggested an edit or resubmitted answer?

P.S Not too late to change.

P.S.S: Just realized it might be a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15839/editing-versus-answering) :(

Comment: Commenting as this is a dupe, but you should add a new answer if you improve it.

Comment: Eh, I'd edit the original answer and leave them a comment to review.  If they don't have enough rep, they can reply in a comment, or if they do they can edit/revert if they aren't happy.