# Make the tag-wiki a real wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, tag-wiki

Regarding the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq/49723#49723) system that was recently implemented on SO. I think requiring 100 upvotes in one particular tag to contribute to these pages is too high.

Firstly, trust the populace! I don't have to provide credentials to edit some detail about the decliene of the Byzantine empire on wikipedia. If the page is intended to be a wiki then it should behave like one. Anyone, even users who are new to the site, should feel welcome and trusted to read these pages and contribute.

Secondly, the success of wikipedia and wikis in general, derives from the fact that expert knowledge about a given topic provides a *very* small percent of the work necessary to make an informative page about that topic. The success of the tag wiki system is dependent on a veritable army of people who are relentlessly fixing grammar, reviewing the text for clarity, re-organizing content and providing depth to the pages by linking to them as many relevant SO questions as possible. In fact, the people who are the most qualified and probably the most motivated to make these changes are the non-experts who come to those pages to learn from them.

(A [similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/lower-the-rep-required-to-edit-community-wiki-posts-or-stop-calling-them-wiki) request - now status complete)

**Important Edit:**

There seems to be a misunderstanding. According to the meta thread I linked, the requirement for editing the tag-wiki page is "if you have more than 100 *upvotes* on non-wiki answers with that tag you are entitled to edit the wiki section." This is very different from 100 rep.

I agree with both @Robert Harvey and @Tim Post. Feature request: make the reputation requirements for tag-wiki the same as community wiki - 100 **rep** not 100 upvotes *(from non CW answers in a particular tag)*.

Comment: The similar request you linked to reduced the rep requirement for editing a Community Wiki post from 750 to 100. Requiring 100 rep for the tag wiki seems consistent.

Comment: @Robert Except tag wiki needs 100 score to edit, and that's at least 1000 points. (not that I approve of this suggestion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Completed, all registered users can now submit edits to tag wikis.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, after earning 100 up-votes in a certain tag, you would have a reasonable grasp of the typical problems that are intrinsic to that tag and no problem articulating them. This helps people reading the tag wiki to avoid common pitfalls when asking questions.

I've seen several posts asking for feedback for what should go into various tag wikis. Prior to earning 100 up-votes in the tag, you could always bring your ideas to meta.

I don't think the threshold is meant to discourage or disenfranchise people, I think it helps to make sure that the wiki stays short and concise enough to be effective.

Comment: You can easily gain 100 rep in a tag on your first day with one simple post - did you mean to write 100 upvotes?

Comment: @George - Thank you for pointing that out, yes.