# What should be required to edit tag-wiki?

Tags: discussion, reputation, tag-wiki

This is a follow up to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59587/make-the-tag-wiki-a-real-wiki) feature request which was not well received.

According to the [default/empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=matlab&sort=info&pagesize=50) tag-wiki page:

> Tag wikis can be edited by users with
>   more than 2000 reputation, provided:
>
> 1. They are in the top 20 answerers for this tag or
> 2. They have more than 100 answer upvotes in this tag

Do you agree with this reputation/upvote requirement (which is *significantly* above the CW editing requirement)? 
If not, what should be required to edit tag-wiki?

Comment: Is this still valid? It now says you must have a "score" of more than 100 in a tag. What does "score" mean and how does it differ from upvotes?

Comment: Score=upvotes-downvotes

Answer (score 7):

I do agree with it. Community-wiki is designed specifically to allow more people to edit the post than would otherwise be able to; tag-wikis are not that way despite having "wiki" in the name, they have considerably more visibility than a single question. Needing to edit one should be fairly rare I would expect; if you do need to add something that's not already there you probably already have the 100 upvotes/2000 reputation needed

Comment: And, as mentioned in the linked question, if you don't meet the requirements you can also bring it up on meta.

Comment: I'd agree with Michael.

Comment: Just now, with the feature being new, a *lot* of the tag wiki *do* need editing. They should settle down pretty quickly, but...

Answer (score 2):

After being implemented for a few months, the tag-wiki pages are [relatively](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info) [concise](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) and [short](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/linq/info).

**IMHO:**

If the purpose of tag-wiki is to give a very brief overview of the tag at hand, then the current rep requirement is fine. If however, we hope to make a comprehensive, authoritative, well sourced and well linked learning resource, then I believe editing privileges should be opened up to the general public wikipedia-style (or at least the rep requirement should be significantly lower).