# Error message returned when attempting to post with a non existant tag could be made clearer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

I ended up with a non-existant tag in the tag field of a new question.  When I attempted to post it I got this error message:

> Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:
>
> - new users can't create tag 'visual'

I'm not sure if this is because I don't have enough reputation (in which case the [faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow)'s statement about needing 100 to do so is incorrect (I have 121 on SO) [EDIT:  It's dated], or something else entirely.

IF the issue is my not having enough rep explicitly stating that fact would be better since 'new' implies a time based criteria not an activity based one.  If the issue was something else then the message should be changed to indicate what the actual error was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this could and should be improved!

EDIT: OK, I improved a number of new user post validation messages. I believe getting the new user experience right is extremely important, almost more important than improving features for heavy users.

In particular I am thinking of Jon Skeet's [What's the single biggest barrier to entry on SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/481/whats-the-single-biggest-barrier-to-entry-on-so)

Comment: Suggestion: "Users with less than XXX reputation points can't create new tags.
The tag 'visual' is new, and you have YY reputation points.
There may be an existing tag that you should use instead; perhaps 'visual-studio'?"

Comment: retracile:  I like your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree the word 'new' is kind of vague, but the FAQ for meta is not the same as the FAQ for SO.

StackOverflows reputation limit for creating new tags is actually 250.

Comment: Am I missing something indicating that the faq post I linked to was for meta only?  The only faq I can find is hosted on meta (with a note indicating it was migrated from SO) and I always assumed it was for all the sites.

Comment: Also if that faq is for meta only, where is the SO specific faq located at?

Comment: @Dan, no, I don't think you missed anything, unless I missed something as well. I believe that answer is just incorrect. If you click the faq link at the top of the site (next to the search box) you'll see the actual reputation information. It appears to be different between MSO and SO.

Comment: @Dan, also that answer was originally posted over a year ago. It's likely that the limit was just changed later on and the answer was never updated to reflect that.

Comment: Too bad, since that faq is much more detailed than the one linked to at the top of the page.