# Where IS the Stack Overflow FAQ?

Tags: support, search, new-users, help-center

Apologies if is this is obvious (or if this is the wrong place to ask), but:

How do I navigate Stack Overflow? Where is the Stack Overflow FAQ, or introduction for beginners/newbies?

I can understand if the answer is some form of RTM.
In that case my question is "Where **is** *The Manual*?"

This site (meta) seems a more appropriate place to ask than Stack Overflow itself, and, after some exploration, the question seems to apply to many Stack Exchange sites.

I've actually learned a little more by browsing the Meta Questions & Answers, particularly [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and [What's the single biggest barrier to entry on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/481), but I still think this is a good question.

I didn't bother doing `s/StackOverflow/StackExchange/g` in the following, in some cases it wouldn't apply.

In general, I am finding the site overwhelming.  I would like to find previous answers to my questions, before asking, but I don't know how.

I would love to find (unanswered) questions that I might be able to answer, but again, too much to wade through.

The tour is great, and explains the overall philosophy well.
I have browsed the help center, and read much that is helpful:

I have tried doing the following searches in the help center:

- beginner's introduction to Stack Overflow - 98 results

  - Privilege: access to moderator tools - Access reports, delete questions, review reviews
  - etc…
- +beginner's introduction to stackoverflow - 1 result
      * What are tags, and how should I use them?
      helpful, but…
- stackoverflow faq                     - 8 results

  helpful, except for where **is** the FAQ ?

My attempts at Stack Overflow search:

- Beginner's introduction to StackOverflow      - 15 results

  - static object creation
  - text box message in visual basic
  - starting activity after list view item is clicked
    …
- how to search stackoverflow   - 5,103 results     !!
- Navigating StackOverflow      - 764 results

  - nothing obviously helpful in first page
- StackOverflow FAQ         - 412 results

  - nothing obviously helpful in first page
- Where is StackOverflow FAQ    - 59 results

  - nothing obviously helpful in first page
- Where is "StackOverflow FAQ"  - 3 results

  - millions of photos on web server
  - NOKIA N9 pppd
  - SVN repository

Hope I didn't go overboard with beginner's Markdown.

Even though I'm a newbie to Stack Overflow, I am a systems programmer with decades of experience. I fondly remember participating in the (pre-Eternal-September) `comp.sys.*` & `comp.lang.*` Usenet groups. I know that probably means squat nowadays, but there may be others out there in my position.

Comment: We are not *that* bad around here. Congrats for asking nicely and in a good spirit, though bit too long... :-)

Comment: Don't forget about meta.stackoverflow.com and the [faq] questions you'll find there.  Also, there's a [faq-proposed] tag with lots of good info as well.

Comment: If this is not only about [so] then http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931 would seem to be the place to start.  It was over in the sidebar at right.

Answer (score 15):

Either here or on any site's meta search for questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) or [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed). Stack Overflow's can be found [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).

These will give you most of the information you need.

As you've already discovered there is also the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help) pages for each site linked to from the menu bar at the top of every page:

[image: Screenshot of ? dropdown expanded to show the Tour, Help Center and Meta links]

These pages give a lot more information on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Note also that in the past, "FAQ" referred to the `/faq` page, which no longer exists.