# Allow an edit to notify downvoters: "I think I've fixed the issue now - please check"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, down-votes, notifications

To me, a downvote usually indicates a problem with an answer. When I downvote it's to mark the *answer* as having a problem, not the person. If the answer is fixed, I want to remove that downvote - but it's tricky to keep track of all the questions I've looked at over the last few hours.

I don't actually downvote very much, but it's very easy to forget what's going on.

It would be nice to have some way of indicating in an edit that you (the editor/answerer) believe the reason for the downvote has now been resolved, so that the downvoters could come and undo their downvotes *or* explain why it's still not fixed.

(Note: this isn't about rep-recovery, but quality control. I would feel a lot better about downvoting on "iffy" answers if I felt it was likely that the answer would be fixed and I could undo the vote. Whether or not I'd get back the cost of the downvote is somewhat immaterial.)

Comment: This would only work if you gave a hint as to what was wrong with the answer that warranted a down-vote ;)

Comment: Well yes - which means it's another encouragement to do exactly that :)

Comment: And what about the time limit on changing your vote - would that then have to be changed?

Comment: @a_m0d: Yes, I think so.

Comment: I wonder how this would affect serial down voting. It could discourage some who don't want to be notified for bogus downvotes, but it may provide a payoff for others who would enjoy seeing their victims reaction.

Comment: Note: this is basically resolved now, given the new comment notification features: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/be-notified-when-someone-leaves-a-comment-that-is-a-direct-response-to-my-comment

Comment: @Æther While that change *helps*, I am not sure I agree it is resolved. perhaps Mr. Skeet could advise?

Comment: @Jeff: It only helps if you left a comment and the answerer then replies back to you. Automatic notification of anything you've downvoted would give more blanket coverage.

Comment: Is this still an issue? While I'd like to be able to find which posts I've cast each vote on (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/finding-the-questions-answers-that-ive-voted-on) and I love getting notified of anything, I also think you can accomplish that by using comments rather than downvoting, and save the nasty votes for questions that are actually bad based only on that. So I don't see any reason for "notification of votes".

Comment: @Jeff: Also, this would help from the other side: when I was the one who wrote the answer, and the downvoter did not comment at all. Being able to send some comment (like `@downvoter`, as I see sometimes) which the downvoter would then see, would be nice.

Comment: Seeing you now can see a list of your downvotes in your user profile it takes us some of the way there.

Comment: @a_m0d The votes are (now) open after an edit.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-review]? Please?

Comment: @Doorknob You can always try a bounty...

Comment: I'd prefer the opt-in [Allow me to get notifications on specific down-voted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165962/146482), or ideally a combination with your proposal consisting of a simple "Notify _watching_ down-voters"-checkbox when editing a post

Comment: @Tobias Never works with [status-declined] stuff :(

Comment: @Doorknob [yeah?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/63057/revisions "suboptimal example, I know, it's just the first one that came to my mind")

Comment: @Tobias That was almost a year later... Probably had no effect

Comment: I think this would pretty much fix 99% of complaints. It’s a better incentive to fix questions.

Comment: Can the mods please change this to status-review? It's pretty evident that the community has a shared mindset on this.

Comment: Is this resolved now, given the new comment notification features? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/

Comment: @rubo77: No, because the OP may not have added a comment. (And I may not have added a comment when downvoting.)

Comment: I created a Question How to [keep track about your edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230987/keep-track-about-your-edits)

Comment: I've posted a variation on this feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231200/add-a-profile-tab-that-shows-edits-to-posts-youve-downvoted), in hopes that something with the same purpose might be implemented :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/294602/1947286

Comment: @JonSkeet, This seems like a really useful idea. Why is it rejected with status-declined?

Comment: @Pacerier: I don't know - but I'm not sure it's that important.

Comment: @Pacerier Jeff explains the reasoning in [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52628/152859). Personally I disagree with that reasoning and downvoted the answer, but back in the time, Jeff was the one with final decision. Not sure the new team will reverse his decision, but worth trying.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, Ugh, many of the meta threads here are getting severely outdated. None is doing follow-up.

Comment: @Pacerier what do you mean? What follow up? This hasn't changed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's moved up in rank. It's now the 19th highest voted question (out of 70k+) on the site. (Although not yet the highest status-declined question.)

Comment: @yEz I don't think that votes alone will affect the team's decision, SE isn't really a democracy. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Still, Jeff said: "this is a good idea". So even he agreed, right?

Comment: @serv-inc agreed but declined. It's like an actor in Audition: they can say "you did well, **but**..." the important part is the "but", i.e. the final outcome. :)

Comment: I'm aware this is a now ancient suggestion, but in the wake of the recent blog post about making StackOverflow a more welcoming place, is there scope for revisiting?

Comment: lets not please.

Comment: If i don't leave a comment on the post i'm voting on, i don't have any interest in being notified of changes to it. If i do leave a comment, they can @ me.

Comment: @snailboat: I wrote a [userscript to filter the downvote list to show only those that have been edited](https://stackapps.com/questions/6755/get-a-list-of-posts-youve-voted-on-that-have-been-edited). It's not linked from here, but from a couple of near-duplicates and such-like. It works fairly well, but it can take as long as a few minutes to pull together the list.

Comment: see also [Implicitly follow by downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359935)/238205

Answer (score 198):

I totally agree with [Ólafur Waage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch/1752#1752)'s idea:

> Or you could have a passive listing in
>   your recent history area where you can
>   see a recent list of edited questions
>   of things you have "upvoted",
>   "downvoted", "commented"

I'd only extend it to add in that listing all new comments on questions where you've commented. Now is a bit of a pain to have comment threads in an answer, having to review recent list and go check if there's anything new on it.

Comment: +1, though [Allow me to get notifications on specific down-voted questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165962/146482) would be more specific

Comment: The problem with this resolution is that edits do not always mean the problems stated or implied have been fixed - on the author side this means an inability to communicate you've made a significant improvement and on the reader side the recent edits are more noise than a list of "Author Fixed" or some more relevant list.

Comment: -1 This is *not* sufficient. This is *not* a notification.

Comment: I like this; you can choose to review this at any time instead of  feeling the need to click on that nagging red icon :)

Comment: I would be happy enough with this solution; I would *not* want an intrusive inbox notification every time someone edits a post I've downvoted. Particularly now that such notifications *buzz my phone* - I would end up wanting to create sockpuppets just to down-vote the posts again...

Answer (score 184):

I'd notify the downvoter *any time* a downvoted question is updated *or* commented, without any option from downvoter to turn it off, except lifting their downvote or the answer being deleted.

Downvoting, in my opinion, should imply more responsibility than just losing a point of rep and forgetting.

Usually, if an answer is irrecoverably bad, it keeps being downvoted until the answerer gets the message and deletes his answer, which is not a problem.

But if there is heavy activity or heavy discussion on the answer, there certainly is something about it, which should force a downvoter to keep an eye on the question.

A couple of updates from the comments:

- Individual sites can opt in or out (this was posted when only Stack Overflow was around)
- It make sense to notify the downvoters only if the score goes up compared to what it was at the time of the downvote
- A debounce interval of a week or so can be added ("ok, it's still bad, but I'll ping you again in a week if the post keeps getting action")

Comment: +1 Actually, when you think about it, the same should hold for any vote.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: sorry for resurrecting an old thread! But actually, good answers turn bad much much more rarely than vice versa. So making users to track upvotes complicates their lifes over the usefullness (unlike tracking downvotes).

Comment: I'm the one who resurrected an old thread. ;p Agreed, tracking _all_ votes would require too much work.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: for any vote it would create way too much noise. Normally posts get better not worse, I'd consider it very rare to see edit worth undoing upvote.

Comment: When a bad post gets chain edited or lots of comments on it that ends up spamming the user for taking action on a bad post.

Comment: @JoeW: so when the user does take action and the bad post becomes good, should the downvotes stay?

Comment: That doesn't justify forcing inbox spam on a user who is taking correct action on a post. Not all posts can be saved through edits and user shouldn't be forced to get spammed as edits happen to the post or comments get added. There are questions on sites that I visit that get dozens of edits and dozens of comments none of which stop it from being a bad post.

Comment: @JoeW: when I first read your comment, I thought that "spamming the user for taking action" meant "spamming the original poster, urging them to correct the post", but now I see that you meant "spamming the downvoter for downvoting an answer they think is beyond redemption". So what if the others think the post got improved (say, when its score goes above what it had been when you cast your downvote)? I would say that the downvoter should get notified if this happens, maybe with a debounce interval of a week or so. ➡

Comment: @JoeW: This suggestion, by the way, was posted when only StackOverflow was around, and for the most part, its answers tend to be less polarizing. Probably it should be implemented on a site by site basis, because I can see how it can go wrong on, say, politics that you seem to frequent.

Comment: I am not saying that having a system to notify when a post you vote on gets updated but it should be something that the user choses to opt into on each post that they vote on.  And this should be available for all posts as a posts quality can go down over time as well.

Answer (score 137):

Similar in principle, though lighter-weight, than [dasblinkenlight's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157249) would be to **have the downvotes section on one's own profile have a simple indicator when a post has been edited since the vote action**.

Then those people who care about responding to edits by withdrawing their downvotes have an easy place to check; and people who don't care don't get any new UI to distract them.

Mockup (sorry, the stars aren't freehand...) of what my page ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/151211/aakashm?tab=votes&sort=downvote, but only I can see that) might look like:

[image: downvotes area with stars next to some post titles]

Comment: I want to point out that this option would be *incredibly* easy to implement. Votes already have a status of whether they are locked or unlocked. Basically, just indicate next to the vote which state it's in (locked or unlocked). Votes can only be unlocked if the post has been edited, so a user can logically conclude that an unlocked vote means the post has been edited since they cast their downvote. You can even apply this to the upvotes tab too, for those who are interested.

Comment: A take-off of this idea - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247609/248652

Comment: @animuson are you going to speak to the devs or does it need to go through the normal channels? There would also (preferably) be a "don't show this for the first 5 minutes" as it isn't' locked then.

Comment: [Follow up feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/276517/245360)

Comment: Has anybody written a user script that does this?

Comment: Re *"people who don't care..."*: well that's the problem.  When the paint dries on a park bench, a *"wet paint"* sign is removed -- leaving a *"wet paint"* sign on the (dry) bench forever is useless and publicly signals custodial neglect.  (Suppose a poor question is downvoted, then revised into a good question.  That quote seems to imply that *not caring* about one's downvote is an always-valid choice, rather than a once valid choice that becomes an error after a latter revision fixes things.)

Comment: @user278533: [I wrote a script that can compile a list showing only the edited posts](https://stackapps.com/questions/6755/get-a-list-of-posts-youve-voted-on-that-have-been-edited)

Answer (score 61):

It kind of seems that the people have spoken here:

> [image]

330 up vs. 15 down at the moment, not to mention the 4 bounties. It looks like this is a pretty popular idea, and has been for some time now.

I know this isn't a democracy, but if user input is really valued give it a shot.

Comment: Make that _5_ bounties. I'll remove my downvote when I get a notification this has been edited ;)

Comment: FTR in 2019 the votes currently stand 791 (upvotes) 
and  42 (downvotes)

Comment: @ColeJohnson  make that 10 bounties.

Answer (score 41):

I like the idea, but I am wondering about the implementation.

You could have one of two things (just brainstorming here):

- An editor changes the question / answer and checks a field called something like "Notable improvement".
- This sends a notification (either via the top bar or the envelope) to all downvoters (and possibly even all the commenters and other editors).

Or you could have a passive listing in your recent history area where you can see a recent list of edited questions of things you have "upvoted", "downvoted", and "commented"

(Upvoted also since you could change your mind if the essence of the question could change over time and you no longer agree with the current state of it.)

Comment: Alternately, you could have a checkbox on the question object itself (answer or question) that says "Notify me if this is edited" Then toss it into the 'recent events' feed.

Comment: [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483/146482)

Comment: I think any reduction of spamming should be handled server side, not as an opt-in. I believe that if someone has the privilege of downvoting, then it should be reasonable to saddle them with the expectation of ruling on appeals (significant edits, either detected by server, or as an option upon editing). If the answer never gets edited, the downvoter never get notified. If the downvoter isn't active, the downvoter won't get notified. If the downvoter is active, they *should* be encouraged to follow up when the answering party is also following up.

Comment: There’s even a substantial edit box getting implemented soon, so this would require no design work either.

Answer (score 38):

I would enjoy this. I too apply temporary down-votes until solutions are cleaned up/corrected. This would be a great feature.

Comment: I used to do this until the undo-vote window became so tight that it's virtually impossible to get back to the post in time to undo.

Comment: @Ether: You are always able to undo a vote if the post was changed in between.

Answer (score 34):

I would go further, and create a queue of everything that I have downvoted that has since been edited. The queue would look and behave similar to the queue of reviews, but it would be private.

The queue should let me walk through questions and answers that I downvoted, display the cumulative edits applied since the moment of my downvote, and give me three buttons - <kbd>Keep the downvote</kbd>, <kbd>Remove the downvote</kbd>, and <kbd>Vote up</kbd>.

Comment: That would be a pretty significant development effort for something that's likely to only be used by a small percentage of users.

Comment: @Servy Well, downvoting in general is a rare activity: I randomly sampled users who are around 1% top voters overall; the number of downvotes ranges from roughly one per day to one in 20 days. I predict, however, that downvoting would become more widespread once the feature is implemented, because the workflow would become a lot smoother.

Comment: You need to consider not only the amount of downvotes among active users, but the number of users who would actually bother to go through such a queue to evaluate items.  I imagine most wouldn't; either because they didn't know of it, or because it was too much bother.  Some would, and it would be nice, but many wouldn't.  My criticism here is merely that the opportunity cost of implementing this is high; I would personally use it quite a bit if it actually came out.  I know I'm not a typical user though.

Comment: @Servy - Perhaps the implementation of this answer is a bit "extreme", but I like it. It would be automatic, so no involvement (checkboxes...) by anyone to make it work. Plus it's only shown if you visit that tab in your profile. For me, right now, I never downvote anything. This is because I feel that if I downvote a question or answer, I have a responsibility to remove my downvote if the question/answer is ever improved. Since I currently can't track those edits (short of frequently visiting all Q/A's I have ever downvoted), then I can't, justify downvoting. If I could track it, I'd downvote

Comment: @KevinFegan See I consider it a responsibility to downvote answers that are harmful because the negative effects of a reader reading an incorrect answer, or worse still an answer with subtle problems that still appears to work at first glance, is very significant, and as such it's very important that readers have an indication that there's a problem with an answer.  Having a bad answer not downvoted is far worse in my mind than having an answer that was bad, but is now fixed, that has downvotes from when it was still bad.  This also incentivizes users to post answer correct from the start.

Comment: A feature like this might encourage downvoting, not saying that's a bad thing

Comment: @axrwkr Downvoting is a good thing only when it encourages posters fix their errors. I do not downvote over smaller issues as much as I could have been because there's no notification for me to go over corrections.

Comment: I think that this answer should be changed to a feature request question

Comment: As long as it doesn't light up my inbox so i can ignore it.

Comment: Could you post this as a seperate feature request please?

Answer (score 34):

With the User Profile having so much in it now, it would be a simple matter to add an `edited-downvote` section to the Votes tab, like so:

[image: Edited Downvote button]

If we were to have a general notification of edits after downvotes, I'd put a time limit on it, like three days.  I don't want my whole history notifying me of any edit like that.

Answer (score 29):

I've long suggested this kind of thing in a more generic sense. Basically my idea (now a stagnant [UserVoice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UserVoice#History) ticket) is that your recent activity view should include:

- Answers to your questions
- Comments on your answers or questions;
- Edits to content you've downvoted; and
- *Any* activity in a question you've favourited.

Of which this is one example. Basically, the current mechanism is a little too crude for a good workflow. The point of a downvote should be to improve an answer but the UI doesn't help you at all in this regard. You have to somehow keep track of downvotes (yes, I know there’s a votes view) given and manually check them for modification. It should be easier than that.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the idea of using favoriting for the purpose of receiving notifications on everything. I just posted a feature request that is similar to this idea though. See my answer.

Answer (score 26):

I like this idea too as it should help improve the site. If posters see a reclamation of rep after fixing a post then it makes them a) more likely to do it in the future and b) more aware of what a good post looks like.

The only drawback is that it could lead to a lot of notifications and if we send users too many notifications then they could start not only ignoring these, but other ones as well.

A better solution might be to have a tab on your profile - only visible to you - of posts edited since you voted on them (both up **and** down) where you can check the edits and review your vote.

Comment: All downvote&edit notifications can be packed into one notification and reduce the amount of downvote&edit notifications.

Comment: Are you thinking about changing it now that you are a moderator?

Comment: @Yay - what do you mean? I'm just a volunteer, I have little to no influence over what gets implemented on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh, sorry I don’t completely understand how stack overflow works

Answer (score 13):

I think [AakashM's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157699/248652) makes sense, and [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c/157699#comment811431_157699) would be easy to implement - I would only add one aspect.

Part of the reason I see this as an important feature request is because downvoting is an important service and responsibility that users have, and we would want to make it as easy as possible to use effectively.  Burdening users with one more responsibility resulting from their responsible downvoting is one more impediment to being willing to exercise this responsibility.

Notifiying users every time a post was edited would perhaps be overwhelming.  But, with the indication sitting in their "votes" tabs, never notifying them would impose upon them the task of occasionally sorting through every downvote they ever cast to see if it was edited.

Perhaps a friendly middle ground could be to implement as suggested in animuson's comment (displaying the already extant locked/unlocked status of votes), but to add an intermittent notification to the inbox that just says

> You have recently unlocked votes

and clicking on the notification would take you to your votes page.  The notification could be sent at UTC midnight each day where it was relevant. This would give users active notification without cluttering their inbox.

The system already differentiates between upvotes and downvotes, so this could be implemented in such a way to apply only to downvotes.  And in order to not need to sift through the entire list, the recent changes could be highlighted in the same way that the reputation page of the profile highlights those items which are new since the last time you visited that page.

People who aren't interested in following up on their downvotes could follow a very simple method - click the red inbox, and then click anywhere else on the page, and **poof** the notifications will go away!  Magic!  This won't *force* anyone to follow up on their downvotes - it will just give them notice that there is what to follow up on, and they can feel free to ignore it, just like anything else that shows up in their inbox.

(A shortcoming of this approach - it would only notify the first time that a post was edited, at which point the vote becomes unlocked. If the post was edited again, it wouldn't register because the vote status wasn't changed. If anyone has a workaround to this, please leave a note.)

Comment: I have thousands of downvotes across SE. Granted, a number of them are on now-deleted posts, but still, I don't want a notification every time one of the non-deleted ones is edited. That would be overwhelming. I expect I'd be getting a notification every day, many of them redundant with a reply to a comment. No way. Besides, wouldn't your reasoning apply to upvotes too? I have over 80k of those, I'd be doing nothing but filtering that.

Comment: @Gilles One notification every 24 hours would be overwhelming?  Geez, you must have sensitive nerves. How do you deal with responses to your thousands of posts across SE?

Comment: @Gilles It's one notification per day, no matter how many  posts were edited that day.  Just a note that tells you at least one vote has gone from locked to unlocked. So your 80k upvotes would not possibly result in more than one notification per day, _if_ it were implemented in such a way as to notify for upvotes (which I don't see why it would have to be, anyways).

Comment: One notification **per site** where a post that I voted on or downvoted was edited. And if I care about these notifications, I have to review every post, so grouping the notifications by site and day isn't really helpful.

Comment: @Gilles You don't have to review every post.  As suggested, you would have an indication of which ones switched to become unlocked.  You could just review that post.  It could even be highlighted to show which ones changed since you last visited the page, as it is in the reputation profile page. As opposed to the current model, in which if you wanted to be responsible, you have to review every post you ever voted on ever ever, at some reasonable interval, to be a responsible voter.

Comment: There is nothing irresponsible in not reviewing posts that have been edited since you voted on them. The responsibility in the content of a post is on the author. If you want to let the author of the post notify you if they edit their post, leave a comment.

Comment: @Gilles except that you are penalizing someone for a once-upon-a-time poor quality post.  Essentially you are saying "If I am too lazy to leave constructive feedback for my downvotes, we should compound that laziness by leaving no way for me to know to reverse it when it's no longer applicable." I'm not sure what _is_ responsible about leaving a series of downvotes which, if they served their purpose, are now residual penalties for not getting it right the first time.

Answer (score 9):

There is now a ["follow" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661/353011), which can be used on the close-voter/down-voter side to follow a question and get notified about edits to it. It's not quite what was suggested here, but it's probably the best workaround for now.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a great idea, but it would eventually get out of control. I currently have given over 150 downvotes, and received a few (not too many of course =P) As the system gets larger and larger, they're going to be sending out more and more edit updates.

But, I think this idea could work if you added a checkbox somewhere on the post itself (question or answer) that allowed you to say "Send me updates when this is edited".

That way, you could downvote it (comment why you did so) and check the box. When the OP edits the answer, you could go back and upvote them (if their change was satisfactory). But, if you become overrun with 'edited' updates, then you can simply uncheck the box.

This is similar to this question

[What level of notification should we have regarding questions we have posted comments on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/477/what-level-of-notification-should-we-have-regarding-questions-we-have-posted-an-a/1773#1773)

and my answer was almost identical.

But a little caveat on both. There could also be something in your preferences that says "Notify me if any downvoted answers are edited" and then it would 'autocheck' that box when you downvote something.

Answer (score 4):

Another idea:
Posters (starting at low reputation) could get a Review pane to review their own activity from some time ago, both for their downvotes and their comments.

The rules for what goes into that personal review queue could include comments/downvotes on posts that have changed since (and other rules as well, such as suggesting self-delete of "Thank you" comments).

Comment: All users already have [list of posts they downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=downvote) in their profile page. I do agree it can be nice to mark those with recent edits with different color, or at least let us sort the list by activity and not by time of downvote.

Comment: There is another answer here like that, you should add your idea (sorting) there.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this could be incorporated together with [getting notifications for new comments on posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have) (either questions or answers) that you've marked as as "interesting".

So, when you want to *track* a post (perhaps because you downvoted it, commented on it, or for any other reason):

1. You would [request to get notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have/1874#1874) about updates (tick a box or something)
2. When the post is edited, or a follow-up comment on it is posted, you'll be notified (via the envelope & Recent Activity page)

A bit like what devinb commented [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch/1752#1752), but using the same UI for keeping up with any activity (both edits and comments) on a post.

Granted, this would not be as fine-grained as some might want (e.g. you'd be notified also about new comments even if you were only interested in an edit that fixes the problem in an answer). But on the bright side, this would largely solve both this FR and the [comment-tracking one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/make-recent-activity-and-responses-show-new-comments-on-questions-answers-i-have), without cluttering the UI with too many options.

Answer (score 3):

It should be restated that the mechanism of downvotes at present can, in certain cases, have a **negative** impact on the overall quality of the site. Specifically on Philosophy SE, where there are lesser numbers of users, some of the concerns with edit notification may not apply. Also Philosophy SE, and possibly other SE's, there is a slightly different flavor to questions and answers. Philosophy has a nascent element of **debate** which can be partially catered for by empowering downvoters to review edits, while allowing PSE to keep to the general question - answer paradigm.

> Enabling edit notification for downvotes will greatly improve content on Philosophy SE

So I propose that, if not for SE as a whole, *then at least give individual communities the option to enable edit notification.*

Also if anonymity is a concern: *When a downvote is cast enable an option to comment anonymously to that content*.

> see also: [Should downvotes have explanations?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3708/33787)

Answer (score 2):

I think this would be a cool feature people can earn by increasing their reputation.

1. It would be a special type of down vote people who have a certain amount of reputation points get.
2. When used it will send a message (with details on what needs to be fixed) to the person being downvoted.
3. When the downvoted person addresses the problem they can respond with a button click indicating the problem is resolved.
4. The person who originally downvoted can then either give more feedback or mark their issue as resolved.

Both users can have a Badge that has a notification counter (right along with the others in the top right e.g. Recent Achievements). This will let the user know when they have a resolvable downvote (on their question/answer) or when someone request the user to resolve a downvote they cast.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the change to the vote change time limit would make this unworkable.  Unless the fix is done immediately, you won't be able to change your vote.  Since the vote time limit change was shortened to prevent gaming, it's unlikely to be changed.  If it were extended, the changes to random sort ordering would have to be rolled back as well as that is one of the main complaints against it -- the ability to down vote to increase your relative visibility and then come back later to recover your rep points after your answer has been upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This feature would be even more useful for questions. I had a question which was strongly downvoted, so I tried to improve it by editing, unfortunately nobody will ever see this edits, as questions below certain score do not appear in the active feed. So at least if the downvoters would see the edit they could change their mind.

Comment: I'm pretty sure any question activity gets into the tag active feed, no matter the score. And that is where the SME's are that can judge if your question warrants an upvote, therefor reversing the score.

Comment: @rene pretty sure author here means the active tab in homepage, and questions below certain score are indeed not shown there. Only few people bother to check the actual "feed" showing questions with any score so it's a good point.

Comment: The threshold for `/` (e.g., "[Top Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)" here) is approx. -8. Currently *[Which sites have additional requirements to become a nominee in moderator election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385823)* (-6) is shown whereas *[Why can new users only answer every 30 minutes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/385819)* (-11) isn't. In contrast to on the upper left → "Questions" ("[All Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest)").

Comment: I tested this today (on [MSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)). At -8 it isn't shown. At -7 it *is* shown.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum The value seems to be depending on the coresponding SE comunity.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Looks like this is the only site with such high threshold: https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6519/41763

Answer (score -12):

At the risk of igniting a flame war (and/or downvotes without discussion about how to take an idea and make it better to solve the problem) about removing anonymous, uncommented downvotes...

Make downvotes a separate item, either as a section or in-line with comments (which would preserve the time-order).  Make them attributable to the downvoter and require a comment of a given length.

Then provide people the ability to concur the downvote.  The downvote and the concurrences would count as the existing downvote count.  This might still allow anonymous downvoting via concurrences, but the problem is identified, can be responded to, and can later be marked as fixed, eliminating the downvote cast.

Likely, marking a downvote fixed would require a certain reputation.  This would also allow one person to sweepingly remove someone else's downvote and all concurrences.

This has many upsides.  Perhaps some newbie garners several downvotes with concurrences causing a substantial downvote count.  Before they even check this, reviewers fix some of the original downvotes.  They return to find the corrections in place and only the now appropriate remaining downvotes.  They fix them.  Someone acknowledges this and marks the downvotes fixed.  Now the voting is where it is now appropriate to the current state.

If a downvote states a reason, such as, "Poster did not research subject," when someone notes that research has been done, why shouldn't they be able to reflect that?  The objective is good questions and good answers.  This allows a policy where people can edit other people's posts.  If my post isn't exclusively locked to me, why should a criticism (which should be appropriate) that has been appropriately addressed?

Right now, if you have the reputation you can downvote anything you don't like without comment or attribution.  This is considered by many to be a virtue.  It is not at all.  There is no debate.  There is no discussion.  There is no appeal.  There is no ability to fix.  And the reason need not be supported by the rules.  If you don't like it, that is good enough to downvote -- no one will know.

The poster's question is about asking someone to revisit their downvote.  If they don't want to, no amount of tweaking this system to "help" will change that.  So I propose that the community should be able to address it.  The first response is, "They can, by upvoting."  But that is false.  Upvotes are for "good", not "problem fixed."  These are not at all the same thing.  You should not vote "good" for "fixed."

As to the same issue with upvoting...  I have no problem at all requiring attribution and comments to upvotes.  People won't like that it takes longer.  Sure a popup with pick your reason including "I want to know the answer" or "Very well prepared" or a field to free type would be fine by me.

But, this eliminates the free fire-and-forget anonymous, uncommented downvote...

Comment: Wait, so if it's not "good", how is it "fixed"?

Answer (score -70):

While this is a good idea, I think @name comment notifications gets us close *enough* to this.

In other words, if someone leaves a comment about why your post is wrong, you can now reply to them and they'll be notified.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

I think it's a bit of a lost cause to expect or anticipate downvoters who didn't leave a comment, to come back and change their vote.

Comment: I don't comment on most downvotes but I would revoke them if the post is corrected.

Comment: but since most downvotes dont come with a comment, perhaps the answerer could do an @downvoters to notify the people who downvoted (this would also help keep downvoters anonymous)

Comment: Sadly this becomes a pain in the ass and doesn't quite work: If there is already a comment explaining a downvote, I don't won't make an own comment, but I will just upvote that comment. The answerer/questioner won't find out about me then - how could he message me? And also, only the first "@name" gets processed - what if there are multiple downvote comments (possibly addressing different things)? The poster would need to write multiple comments with one "@name" in each, or edit his comment to contain a different "@name" each time - i think this is a PITA.

Comment: I would like to propose to reserve the name "downvoters" (hey, I just see @Neil had this idea already. duhh :)). This name would refer to all the users that downvoted the answer. A user that fixed problems could say "@downvoters, I fixed this and that. Please review".

Comment: @johannes would lead to much bellyaching and infighting in my opinion.

Comment: If someone downvotes for a reason someone else already commented about, they almost surely won't comment again. Also, the time limit can easily be fixed by resetting the time limit for edited questions/answers.

Comment: This is the official response, yet it has a very negative score. The question has a high score, as do many of the other answers that suggest implementation ideas. At what point is the question open for debate again? I appreciate this is not a democracy, but this is clearly something the users want!

Comment: I agree; requesting a re-review of this.

Comment: The standing policy of pretty much every SO veteran I know is not to comment anymore when downvoting because it only leads to trouble. At the moment, if you have a downvoted contribution on SO, there's absolutely no point bothering to try to fix it - often enough, not enough people will care to offset the downvotes (or assume they are there due to something they haven't spotted). Is that really the message we want to send users?

Comment: If you ever implement this, edit your answer and you'll probably get the best Edit reversal ever seen in SE history.

Comment: Imho this answer is beside the point: There are no notifications on _edits_ to a post on which I have voted in any way. Having at least [a list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1752/170949) which we could check periodically instead of a notification that would help. I'd actually now opt for a list, plus a notification for edits on downvoted closed questions.

Comment: Besides, it's useless or even detrimental (encourages novices to not RTFM) to comment on issues that are already covered by essential reading.

Comment: The vote system is even _designed_ with such a possible feature in mind, since a vote is unlocked when the post is edited.

Comment: Not true. People can peruse and leave downvotes without commenting and would be more than happy to reverse them if they're editing. Also the scene has changed and we're discouraging comment pile on, so there's only so much someone can say, if it's already been said in the comments.