# Conditional Upvote associated with Comments?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, up-votes

I frequently want to say "If you made a certain change to this answer, I'd upvote it". But I don't say that, because it would be a lie, because how would I remember to come back and check?

So how about introducing the idea of a "conditional upvote"?

It could be associated with a comment, so when adding a comment to an answer, you could check a box to say "Conditional upvote". The comment then explains what changes would need to be made to the answer in order for it to qualify for an upvote from the commenter.

The significance would be that I'd be able to go to my profile and see listed all the outstanding conditional upvote comments I've made, and I'd get a notification when the associated answer was edited.

When I upvote the answer, or if a week passes, it disappears from my conditional upvote list.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch

Comment: If you favorite a question it now appears in your favorites changes tab if someone makes a change. Don't know if that includes edits on existing questions, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The last thing we need is 12,000 comments from TheTXI that say "I'd upvote this answer if it contained more ponies."

And to preempt TheTXI's comment:

[image: Ponies!]

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if it...+1

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if the ponies were wearing bowler hats

Comment: I would upvote everything pesto does for the next 7 days if the ponies were wearing bowler hats.

Comment: Damnit, my slightly over-elabourate attempt to prove my own point ("edit the answer yourself?") has been foiled by my lack of editing privileges.. http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/4409/better.jpg

Comment: dbr: Your next task...sweater vests!

Comment: @dbr - Oh, and a fancy rainbow too...smooth. Trot trot trot.

Comment: The rainbow made this irresistably correct.

Comment: I'd upvote this if it had at least 2 unicorns and 10

Answer (score 5):

I just periodically re-check all comments in my "recent" list. Once they roll off the end, too late.

Comment: Me         too.

Answer (score 4):

Please no. No more complexity. The voting system works fine as it is with 'drive by' votes.

Comment: Vrrrrrrrrrroooooom!

Answer (score 2):

This feature was requested. The suggestion was that voters would be informed that solutions were updated. They could then return, and decide if they wanted to up-vote/down-vote.

**Related:** [Allow an Edit to Notify Down-voters: “I think I’ve fixed the issue now - please check”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch)

Answer (score 2):

This seems unnecessarily complicated, hard to explain and of rather limited use..

Couldn't you simply comment on how you think the answer could be improved, and check your last x comments using your [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27423?tab=recent#sort-top) tab?

Or even edit the answer yourself? I can't really think of a case where you would comment "I'd upvote this if [you complete rewrote this answer and totally changed the meaning]" - so the changes are likely to be pretty small, so should be unoffensive to do yourself..

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue with implementing this feature as requested is how could you programatically determine if the person modified the answer in the way requested by the comment. As indicated you can do this fairly easily through a manual process, but I would support the idea of allowing a user to "follow" an answer and get notification of changes to the answer and/or comments added.

Comment: No, my request definitely doesn't propose adding AI to SO.

Comment: That would be AWESOME. I think someone should write some AI to detect good answers and automatically upvote them for me.
Then I wouldn't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding  a feature to SO, you could always use a to-do-list app such as [RememberTheMilk](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/) or [GMail](http://mail.google.com/mail/help/tasks/) to keep track of when to check if an answer has been improved.

Answer (score 0):

Management Answer:

This is not going to happen, complexity is our enemy, this request a massive can of worms.