# Suggestion: allow a poster to flag comments to his or her posts

Tags: feature-request, comments

Often someone will provide a comment that might be a request for clarification or they might be pointing out a simple typo or a problem. When you correct that problem there is no way for the commenter to know things have changed.

How about making it so that you can flag a comment such that the commenter gets notified that the post has changed and that you'd like them to reevaluate their comment.

This shouldn't be an automatic notification (as previously suggested) as you might be correcting or modifying something completely unrelated to the comments. Also the edit may only be related to some of the comments.

To stop possible abuse you'd mark the comment as "flagged" which would remain in place until the commenter dismissed it. With an active flag you can't flag it again.

Additionally you may want to require an edit to flag a comment.

It would also be good to have a tab of such flagged comments available to each user.

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch ... sort of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better if it was just allowed for any user to subscribe to a question or answer and get a notification of any changes (whether it be through system notification or email message). This way only those who actually care to see it will see it.

Comment: I would like that too but that one has not been accepted in the 6+ months it's been around. Who knows? Maybe this one will and I'll take what I can get.

Comment: I would put the chances of the subscription feature being implemented much higher than your current suggestion. But who knows.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the (recently added) ability to sort Favorites by recent activity is sufficient for this. I don't need that little envelope to sporadically turn colors for every little thing.