# Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, notifications, recent-activity

It would be nice to allow users to mark a change in an answer (or question) as minor (e.g. for a simple spelling or grammar correction). A change marked as minor wouldn't push the question on top of the list of questions on the home page or in the feeds. It wouldn't trigger any notification. This could be implemented with a "Minor change" checkbox when editing an entry (a la Confluence). What do you think?

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178490/138389

Comment: I really like this. The only problem is that there are lots and lots and lots and lots of existing edits that would need to be marked as a "Minor Change".

Comment: Related: [Allow non-bumping minor edits, but review them on /review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122567).

Comment: I feel this should be re-evaluated.

Comment: @Martin total waste of bounty. In order to re-consider a declined request, we should start a new request, linking to the declined one, and asking to re-consider while bringing some valid reasons, not just "Please reconsider". If you do post such new request, think you can flag this one and ask for a bounty refund.

Comment: @ShadowtheHatterWizard I have added a bounty in order to attract attention to the issue. In a way, I have paid with a bounty for bumping the question. But you raise rather interesting philosophical question: Can somebody really *waste* something which comes from imaginary internet poitns?

Comment: @Martin sure you can waste, as it leads to actual privileges, and actions you can or can't take on the site.

Answer (score 53):

It would be good if this request were re-evaluated, in light of modern edit reviewing technology.

Paŭlo Ebermann speaks correctly about this issue when it pertains to slower sites. A site that only gets 50 questions per day is still a good site. But if you make 20 edits, you're pushing good questions off the top.

I see this happen on Gamedev.se all the time, when one of the mods goes on a re-tagging spree. It's important to do that kind of maintenance work. But it shouldn't clutter the front page.

This isn't an enforced thing. We're not even asking for the option to be *default*. Just to have it be there for those who need to make a minor change to a post that doesn't warrant it bumping other content off the front page.

We have tools to see people editing posts. We have tools to see people making edits to old posts. We have tools to prevent these people from making malicious edits.

In short: Robert Cartaino♦'s argument about exploitation is simply no longer valid.

Comment: I think such things should be reviewed. If a mod edits tag out of a question probably not, but for non-diamond/non-trusted users? Maybe make it a privilege?

Comment: Old post, but, I support the re-evaluation of this feature request: if we make the feature a privilege only available e.g. from 500 or 1000 rep., then the number/frequency of such minor edits would be made sufficiently low to be curated by other users (or mods), maybe on a dedicated special page. I myself have made spell fixes on a very old post of mine (5+ years), and I gained upvotes for it being bumped on the front page, so I feel a little guilty...

Answer (score 39):

Implementing any sort of "don't bump" functionality **would also delay accountability** and transparency for those edits.

Notifying users of edits in the system allows them to take a look at the content and make sure there isn't something fishy going on. Imagine if people could make changes to the system without *anybody* noticing. **That is very exploitable.**

Comment: Good point. But... would this happen? I mean, Wiki are open and **do** work. Or maybe I'm too naive and it actually happens and people have to revert changes when they notice it. I'm doubting now...

Comment: What if a bot came in and added spam to posts that are long-gone from the front pages. No one would notice for a *long* time.

Comment: Even bumping isn't a perfect solution for that though - if I'm asleep and someone edits a question I've responded to (or similar), what's the odds of it being on the front page when I wake up?
This is why we to be able to have proper notifications for changes to questions/answers we have been involved with.

Comment: @Robert That's what Captcha are for. Bumping is not a solution to bot spam.

Comment: It's not like just because something doesn't bump to the active threads list that there's no other way to track it.  First, users could be prevented from making minor edits until a certain sufficiently high rep, perhaps initially very high (like 5k).  Secondly, there could simply be a tab for minor edits.  Any abuse there, marking obviously non-minor edits as such, or hiding vandalism as a minor edit, could result in a quick ban.

Comment: @Ocaasi I agree. The system could also trigger a Captcha verification for minor edits.

Comment: OK, can I at least fix my own answers then without bumping and without counting as an edit towards the CW count?

Comment: This rationale is weak; I don't think it's worth spamming the front page with mass-edits for the (low) chance that someone will take a look and go "oh look, spam".

Comment: In addition to @Ocaasi's suggestions, these "minor" edits could require peer review before being accepted. (And perhaps even in a separate queue than other edits, so users who don't care to be bothered by them don't have to). As a minor-editor myself, I'd be happy to approve other's minor edits as well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with @Flimzy. Why can't these minor edits be handled exactly like regular edits -- same rep requirements, peer review, etc -- with the only exception being that they don't bump the thread to the front page?

Comment: -1: "Imagine if people could make changes to the system without anybody noticing. That is very exploitable." That's a strawman argument. Well, it is now. We have all the tools necessary to see edits on old posts by random people *without* having the question be bumped. So there's nothing to exploit, and thus this argument is irrelevant.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Maybe something like a check-box which you select to 'opt-out' of bumpation. Then (and I know you probably hate the idea of more review queues) that edit - by the OP or otherwise - gets added to a 'Bumpless Edit' rev queue. This may work on smaller sites, but not where the rev Qs are already huge? Maybe? No? Ok thanks! :)

Comment: Nonsense, any *"minor edit"* flag could be conditional to the edit been small enough to qualify as minor. Spelling edits are easy to identify as such, number of characters changed are easy to count. Also,  this could be a feature restricted to high reputation users.

Comment: Then make the "minor edit" check-box mod-only, or at least a privilege.

Answer (score 16):

*(I just was typing this for a [question which then got closed as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102629/would-we-benefit-the-community-taking-chaos-edit-power) before I finished. I'll post it here, thus.)*

There are several points to think about, here.

The *edit bumps questions to front page* feature has these goals:

- If a question is edited, maybe it is now easier to answer => People should look at it, and maybe upvote/answer it.
- If an answer is edited, it could now be a good answer => People should look at it to upvote it.
- Maybe an edit made something worse. => People should look at it, and maybe revert the edit, if necessary.

On the other hand, bumping many old questions to the front page has the effect that people don't see the new questions anymore.

For example, in the last some days I edited all questions with "question" in the title on tex.stackexchange.com. After about 6 such edits I got a comment request to slow down ... since my edited questions came faster than new ones. I then changed to a "one per hour" rhythm (on average).

(Some of these questions were further edited then by other users, and I think some even got new answers.)

This is particularly bad for small sites - Stack Overflow has no such problem (for normal editing speeds), though it might affect people who follow the tags which I'm just editing.

So, if you simply don't do this too often, the bumping is not a real problem. (Of course, if multiple people do the same, it again gets a problem ...)

I'm not sure how to solve this - maybe have a kind of "approve" feature so another user will confirm that this edit both

- is not malicious
- does not make the post so much better that it should be bumped

Or, as Michael said, simply put a size limit. But some edits (like adding/removing a "not") can quite change the meaning of a post.

Answer (score 5):

As I understood Mr. Cartaino's answer, this suggestion was declined, because misusing the "minor edit" function could make easier to make destructive or invalid changes below the radar. This is right, but the Wikipedia has a solution for this, and a similar solution is what I [suggest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265879/suggestion-having-a-clickable-minor-edit-checkbox-on-edits):

*On the list of the recently changed questions, a "without minor changes" checkbox could exist.*

On my opinion, this would solve the problem of the danger of the misuse of the suggested functionality.

Comment: Quite a few of the Wikipedia edits marked as minor aren't minor at all. I'd say a "suppress some random revisions from view" feature could accomplish the same result.

Comment: @chirlu Wikipedia edits can't be revised, only reverted. If an edit got a "minor" flag, AFAIK it can't be changed any more. Here the "minor edit" flag of an edit could be changed in by the suspended edit reviewers.

Comment: @chirlu Another argument: on the wiki, the only meaning of the "minor edit" box that it won't be visible for the reviewers not wanting to see them. Here would be meaning (losing of the +2, BUT the permission to make cosmetical changes), and in the case of misuses, there would be consequences (changes in the "minor view" boxes, later maybe the cage).

Answer (score 4):

Apologies if this has already been mentioned (there are several more-or-less similar proposals, with multiple comments and answers each, but I have not found the same combination).

How about the following?

1. An editor can click a different (adjacent) button to save as a minor edit. (Single click, not a check box plus click to save.)
2. Such a minor edit would not add much to the editor's rep, since less time, effort, understanding etc. is needed.   It should count for something, however.
3. Likewise, a review of a minor edit should count less for the reviewer rep, for the same reason.
4. A reviewer can choose to see minor edits also or only non-minor edits, the latter by default.
5. When a reviewer views a minor edit it is clearly labeled as such.
6. A reviewer can still decide to reject a minor edit because it is too minor (not helpful), but will typically be less likely to do so.  The edit is not trying to pass itself off as a significant change that is worth much.  It is trying to pass itself off as an improvement, even if minor, and it can be rejected if the reviewer thinks it adds nothing.

The advantage for an editor is that the edit is less likely to be rejected for being too minor.  S?he will get some points for helping a little, but not many points since helping only a little.

The advantage for SO is that cosmetic edits will get done instead of being avoided, improving readability and thus communication.  There might be fewer comments asking for clarification etc., as users help each other by cleaning things up in "insignificant" ways.

An editor can decide at the time of saving whether s?he thinks the edit is worth normal points (and thus risk being closed if a reviewer thinks it is too minor) or worth only minor-change points. IOW, the editor judges the editing result when done, and makes a bet wrt its worth.

#4 might take care of the problems mentioned wrt minor edits being sent to the top/front and crowding out normal edits and creating extra work for reviewers.  A reviewer would see them only by explicitly asking to see them.

Minor changes might not get accepted as quickly, since some reviewers might not bother with them, as they are worth less.  And that might not be altogether bad -- they are after all less important.  But at least they would have a chance at being accepted -- they are some help, even if not a great help.

Again, apologies if these suggestions have been made before.  I didn't find this combination suggested.

---

Postscript: Perhaps another possibility would be to have reviewers of an edit click a new button, `OK as Minor`, which would accept the edit as a minor edit, with as consequence reducing the points to be awarded to the editor.

*I really think it's a shame to reject edits that improve things, even if in only a minor way.* Such edits are being rejected not because they reduce the quality but only to fit the SO rewards system, which in this case is fairly coarse-grained: significant improvement or none. That's not ideal.

Comment: Your point 3 is invalid, there is no rep gained from reviewing.

Comment: @Mat: I didn't mean count less for reputation. I meant count less toward a reviewing badge.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of being denoted manually, some sort of heuristic could be used - e.g. if fewer than 1% of the post's characters have changed, it's a "minor edit". It might be tricky to get right though.

Comment: They already do some of that for display and it is terribly buggy. Why do you think it would be any more accurate if it were controlling functionality?

Comment: I find this more complex and less accurate than a simple checkbox.

Comment: It could be combined with the checkbox. Edits are minor only if flagged as minor and changes are less than 12 characters or easily identified as typo or format corrections.

Answer (score 0):

I am a volunteer Wikipedia editor and it annoys me that I cannot make minor copyedits here. People should be able to make edits of less than 6 characters long.

Comment: The length and copy editing are not necessarily correlated.

Answer (score -3):

Recently Jeff [repeated his opinion](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3103/do-we-care-about-edit-flooding-should-we-be-doing-anything/3131#3131) about not supporting a trivial edit checkbox:

> **I definitely do not support a "trivial edit" or "hidden edit" flag.** All edits need to be vetted by the community, and hiding them is not the right way to accomplish this goal.

(This matches [Robert's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers/26496#26496), and I agree, even though nowadays there's peer review for those <2k.)

Comment: He was specifically talking about *hiding* edits from view. That's not this; we're just talking about removing the bump effect.

Comment: I kind of doubt that, @Nicol, but maybe I am interpreting "[vetted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vetting)" wrongly. Still then, in the comments on the very same answer Jeff writes: *"We want people to look at and review what is on the front page, not sweep it under the rug so lots of weird, bad, secret edits can go on."*