# Mark edit as "minor" to prevent bumping

Tags: feature-request, edits, bump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers)

Minor spelling corrections should *not* bump a question IMHO. Therefore, a checkbox (far away from the CW one please) "minor edit" should be available to signify "this edit did not change anything really important (but the spelling sucked)".

Comment: While I can see the benefit, I don't think it will be well used.

Comment: How exactly would you stop people from using this to do stealth edits that don't get bumped? As Robert indicates in [this answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers "And you know what's going to follow from me posting this"), it is rather exploitable to be able to perform edits without any accountability.

Comment: @Grace good point in Robert's answer...