# Make edits outside suggested edit

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug

I couldn't find a duplicate of this bug/feature-request.

I wanted to make an edit to a question to improve the formatting, however I couldn't because there was an edit pending. When I click the `edit (1)` link, it pops up the review screen but I'm notified:

> Thank you for reviewing 20 Suggested Edits today;

Am I at the mercy of waiting for this edit to be approved before I can edit it? I feel  like I should be able to edit the question whether it's pending or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this can by bypassed by going directly to the post's edit url, `/posts/1234/edit`. Your edit will go through and Community will reject the pending suggested edit.

Comment: @JeremyBanksᐛ For some reason this didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

This has bothered me a few times as well and I've learned to just smile and wave ;-)

There's no easy fix here; for your edit to go through, pending suggested edits must be reviewed first.

You could suggest making your edit automatically "improve" the pending edit, but what if the pending edit is bad and absolutely not useful? Would you undo the other's changes just to push your edit through? Either way it's still a review.

I think this is one of those cases whereby you should slowly [step away from the computer](http://xkcd.com/386/) ;-) leave the question open and come back to it later when the review has finished.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one. I asked [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170545/revisiting-too-minor-edits) about edits and it seems that there should be a way to choose whether the edit was useful in this case.