# Definition of "edited" for triggering community-wiki state

Tags: discussion, edits, community-wiki

Today I encountered an interesting situation. I tend to write with a lot of typos and sometimes use awkward phrasing, which I later edit.

After rewriting an older answer (too bring it up-to-date with my current understanding of subject), I made a lot of mistakes. This resulted in at least 5 different subsequent edits, and triggered "community wiki" mode.

So this is the question-like suggestion, that I got ..

> Shouldn't there be a separation between "large edit" and "fixing typos", based on percentage of content, that was changed?

This way, the fixing "a" to "as" would not count as a full edit, and would avoid triggering wiki-mode prematurely.

Comment: CW should not occur before 10 edits by the original author; see "How does a post become a Community Wiki post?" in [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: @Arjan , the 5 mentioned edits where fixing typos, bringing the total to/over 10.

Comment: Related: [Stop auto-cw for self-edited posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78689/stop-auto-cw-for-self-edited-posts) and [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers?lq=1) (declined).

Comment: 'a to as' would also need to not bump the post to the front page. I like having measures to keep people from editing _just_ to bump answers so they get more visibility, but fixing an "its" -> "it's" mixup landed a few of mine in the same boat. It's easy to trigger when the OP changes the question a few times, or just doesn't understand your example (or other reasons where you make a lot of non trivial edits as well).

Comment: @TimPost , if OP makes major changes to the question, it should be marked for a Review. Such behavior would be quite bad for SO, as it generates answers, which make no sense in context of "current" question. I feel like ability to distinguish between minor and major edits could have a lot of positive use-cases. And ability to stop people from gaming system for "bumps" would be a nice addition.

Comment: [This no longer applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947).

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do a lot of typo and semantic corrections, too, since I'm a bit of a perfectionist. Luckily, there's a five-minute [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20441/is-there-a-grace-period-for-correction-of-edits) for edits.

If your post goes over 10, you should probably ask a moderator to unwikify it. I'm not sure if you can delete your own question once it becomes a wiki, but if you can, that may be an option for you, too.

Meanwhile, you may also want to consider writing your questions/answers off-line, and giving yourself a cooling-off period before pasting it into SO. I do that myself when I have a really long or complex post, and find that it cuts down on the revisions a lot.

Comment: The best thing to do here (even if a change was implemented) is proofread more carefully prior to posting. I fully agree.

Comment: And what if you write you answer late in the evening, post it , an in the morning decide the re-check it ? It would be useful to have ability to create linkable *Draft* versions. You could even drop it in chat and ask some people with more clue to check it out. Though creating draft system would be a quite large addition to the SO infrastructure .. and, I fear, quite abusable.

Comment: I guess the bottom line is simple: don't improve your answers. You get punished for it. Post in time for the OP to *see* it, make it high quality or earn actual rep for it. Pick any two...

Answer (score 1):

I only encountered that on answers I really spent the love. E.g. coming back after some time and so on. And community-wiki does not always apply then.

What you can do in these cases is flag your own answer and ask a moderator to restore to non-community-wiki. This normally works without any problems.

I don't think such things can be reasonable managed automatically or let's say: they don't need to IMHO.