# Answer automatically changed to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion

I've just noticed that a question I spent a great deal of time researching and refining has become a "Community Wiki". Why does this happen? It seems designed to dissuade people from improving their answers :(

Is there anything that can be done with my particular question?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5797523/199700

Comment: "added 32 characters in body; [made Community Wiki by Django Reinhardt editing at least 10 times]" <- Flag for moderator attention and ask to remove the CW status.

Comment: @TinSoldiersAndNixonsComin' Thank you!

Comment: See this post: [What Are Communitity Wiki Posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts?lq=1) If a question / answer gets edited a lot then it automatically becomes a CW

Comment: It gets auto wikied after 12 edits. You did 10 edits in the first 36 hours of its existence.

Comment: It is to [discourage people from bumping the question/answer to the front page by trivial edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78692/209357). If you feel that your edits are genuinely improving the question, flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: So. Much. Bold.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII **Bold means it's important!!**

Comment: I'm curious. Would flagging and asking for removal of CW-status be valid for questions with excessive editing, as well?

Comment: @J.Steen you can always flag it and ask, but it doesn't mean a mod is going to remove the CW-status.  Usually depends on their assessment of the edits and if they were legit edits to fix the post or update the post, vs minor edits to bump the question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well. It's quite an old question that I've answered, that turned into CW through excessive editing. I was merely curious and probably won't flag, even if I'm losing out on 300 rep. =)

Comment: @Antony Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Bart I'm someone who tends to edit like crazy -- rather than convert to CW, why doesn't the system just stop bumping the question after 12 edits? Wouldn't that solve everything?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt without bumping, someone could edit some posts as will, and no one will see the edit unless they happen to look at the question.  Bumping assures that it will show up on the front page so someone will see it.  It's there to prevent people from editing in spam or vandalizing posts.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Questions are bumped to try and prevent spam... REALLY?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Well yes, it makes good sense. I could go and find a tag that hasn't had much activity on it for a while and just edit all the questions to say *"Visit example.com to get some great deals on new Jordan Shoes!!!"* and if these posts didn't get bumped to the front page then this vandalism wouldn't get noticed for quite a while.

Comment: That was me who removed the auto-wiki for you btw.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Thank you, sir!

Comment: @JonW I just assumed that 2,500+ users were trustworthy -- isn't that why their edits don't require moderation?

Answer (score 4):

One reason why a post can turn into community wiki is

> The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.

For the others see [What are community wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

You can see that [in your revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5797523/revisions):

> made Community Wiki by Django Reinhardt editing at least 10 times

Comment: Though the text says "at least 10" it didn't actually get wikied until revison 12 in the [history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5797523/revisions)

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).