# Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

After 11 edits (12 versions) from the same user an answer becomes community wiki. There are lots of questions regarding the way in which this happens but none (that I could find) regarding "Why". And humans hate not to know why!

Most other reasons for community wikification make obvious sense; if a post has been edited by many many users it doesn't really belong to anyone anymore. But the 11 edits creates a perverse incentive not to edit your own posts to perfect them. Previously I would return many times (possibly weeks after I'd posted) to improve a big answer but I basically don't do that anymore unless I can remember exactly how many times I've edited before <sup>or now that I'm not completely new to the site, look at the "edited" link and see that I still have several edits left.</sup>

That's the reasons against this system, but I'm presuming there are reasons for 11 self edits leading to community wikification, which brings me back to why?

## Note

This question refers to a behaviour which no longer exists. Posts are [no longer automatically converted to community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism)

Comment: I think it is actually 12 rather than 7.

Comment: [Is there any point forcing a post to Community Wiki after 6 owner edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/is-there-any-point-forcing-a-post-to-community-wiki-after-6-owner-edits)

Comment: @MartinSmith: *The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner.* [what-are-community-wiki-posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/)

Comment: @juergend - [My comment on your answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178350/145673) though now the CW has been removed from that answer it is no longer visible in the history at revision 12.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thats good news, it seems to change depending on who you ask; 7, 10 and 12 seem to be the common answers

Comment: @RichardTingle - [Here's another example where it happened after revision 12](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3183687/revisions). That one is also a good example where the user was transparently making trivial edits to bump the answer. I suppose being picky you could say that revision 12 was the 11th edit though.

Comment: @MartinSmith That is quite shocking, although that level of unimaginativity could presumably be detected by an algorithm. A question though is; how effective is that, I know I ususally browse via the newest tab

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - That is really not a duplicate. That question is a feature request to stop it while this one is asking the reason behind that feature.

Comment: [This no longer applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is a rate limiting measure, to prevent users from bumping a post to the top too often. It was introduced a long time ago, during the Stack Overflow private beta period, in fact. Jeff and Joel discuss this in [Stack Overflow Podcast #20](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/podcast-20/) (which I happened to listen to just yesterday).

If this bites you for legitimate reasons (your answer evolved over time, following the complexities of a changing question, or because of new insights to a complex problem), flag your post for moderator attention, use `other` and request that a moderator revert the CW flag change.

This has happened to me once or twice, and the flag has always been quickly handled and my request to revert honoured.

Comment: Does editing *still* bump, as far as answers go they seem to show up in a random order

Comment: @RichardTingle: editing answers bumps questions in the 'Active' tab. I believe that site homepages do take active posts into account in what is shown as well.

Comment: This suggests community wikification is being used as a punishment of sorts, surely this wasn't the intention of community wiki? Also; isn't this using a sledge hammer to crack a nut, wouldn't a more direct solution be just to stop bumping after so many edits.

Comment: Bumping is important, we can't supress bumping since that would allow folks to start doing evil stuff after *n* trivial edits, @Richard. An alternate solution would be to simply limit edits to a single post to *n* per day, but of course that might discourage someone from making *useful* improvements (and has other issues once other editors get involved).

Comment: @Shog9, Or only count edits from the last 30 days when for “auto wiki”

Comment: @IanRingrose: [Auto CW is gone, as of yesterday](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227290/stop-using-community-wiki-as-a-reputation-denial-mechanism/228940#228940). *Ding ding, the witch is dead!*