# Why did my question become Community Wiki?

Tags: support, asking-questions, community-wiki

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16589821/996493) on Stack Overflow, but after a few days it became **Community Wiki**. Why?

I think it is related to the number of editions of the question, but I'm not certain.

Comment: question link please

Comment: A link to the question would help. Either too many  people edited the post, you edited it too often yourself, or the question was given 30 or more answers and became CW automatically.

Comment: You edited at least 10 times: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16589821/12

Comment: Thank you anthony this is what I understood.

Comment: The system works. You were obviously trying to get attention (and upvotes) by trivial edits and the system blocked you from gaining reputation this way.

Comment: I'm not so sure about that @ShaWizDowArd. OP continued the trivial edits even after the question was wikified, I think this is more a case of misunderstanding how edits work (the whole bump thing) and less one of intentional rep whoring.

Comment: @Yannis don't think so. Can't see any innocent reason to just add and remove bold from a sentence. Over and over.

Comment: consider CW a measure against abusing edit [meta-tag:bump]s you made in [revisions 5, 9, 11, 12 and 13](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16589821/revisions) of your question

Comment: That... looks fishy indeed @ShaWizDowArd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You edited [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589821/android-app-crashes-after-sdk-tools-update-version-noclassdeffound-tool-versio) more than 10 times, making it a community wiki.

This is a rate limiting measure; don't bump your question with minor edits to get attention so often. See [Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179901/why-does-repeated-editing-by-same-user-lead-to-community-wiki)

If this happened to your post for legitimate reasons (your post evolved over time, following the complexities of a changing question, or because of new insights to a complex problem), flag your post for moderator attention, use `other` and request that a moderator revert the CW flag change.

This has happened to me once or twice, and the flag has always been quickly handled and my request to revert honoured.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as described here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).