# Why does Stack Overflow make all my answers community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki, specific-answer

My recent answers got turned into community wiki (CW) state automatically. I know about answers getting turned into community wikis after 10 edits - which I think is not right anyway if I was the only one editing - but recently it seems to happen with my new answers without edits too:

- [Parallel doseq for Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969708/parallel-doseq-for-clojure/19688295#19688295)
- [Clojure lazy sequences in math.combinatorics results in OutOfMemory (OOM) Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16194841/clojure-lazy-sequences-in-math-combinatorics-results-in-outofmemory-oom-error/17761431#17761431)

Is this a bug or some special [Halloween](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halloween) care? I would like to have them reverted from CW state.

#### Update

I raised flags about both answers. The second one (edited multiple times by me) got reverted back to normal answer, but the first didn't. I flagged the question itself to be reverted back from community wiki status, as only the owner edited it, but nothing happened since. Until it gets fixed I removed my answer too... no such thing as free lunch guys, I want my points LOL ;)

#### Update 2

Yay! Both of them are reverted back!!! :D

Comment: Did you recently install some unusal userscript?

Comment: Not to my knowledge... ohhh... wait... do you think this "Turn SO answers to community wiki" Chrome plugin could be responsible?

Comment: The second was made CW because, as the revision note says, it was edited by you 10 times.

Comment: The latter one is a multiple-edit conversion, as can be seen from the [post history](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7b5wj.png).

Comment: @Werner true, but still I was the only one who was editing it... feels fair to refine your answer to pefrcteion but not get the points for it, yay!

Comment: @DanielDinnyes that could be it. Try disabling it and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @JanDvorak Lol dude, I was joking...

Comment: @DanielDinnyes so was I ;-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You posted the *first* answer on a CW question. All new answers on that question are converted to CW posts. That question became CW because the OP edited the question 10 times.

Your second post, you edited a grand total of 13 times. This is a rate limiting measure; don't bump your question with minor edits to get attention so often. See [Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179901/why-does-repeated-editing-by-same-user-lead-to-community-wiki)

You can flag that post for moderator attention and request it be reverted to a normal post. It doesn't look as if you edited that post *just* to draw attention, so the auto-CW here is unjust and should be reverted without problems. Flag the post, pick 'Other' and make your case to the moderators.

Comment: So if they were legitimate edits, and not bumps to draw attention - then you can have it reverted?

Comment: @JoshC: Yes. This happened to me twice or so, and after a flagging a moderator reverted the status for me in each case.

Comment: That said, it's still a strong sign that you should be taking more care with your edits to edit the post all at once, rather than making lots of small incremental edits.  If this is happening more than very rarely, something is off.

Comment: @Servy: Indeed. Some problems just turn out harder than expected and you keep coming back to the post to handle the corner cases you discover as you play out the solution. But those kind of posts are relatively rare. Out of 6.5k answers, it happened to me twice or so.

Comment: Wish I could say the same of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21262268/1810429) hit by auto CW conversion, @MartijnPieters!  Not the end of the world...but definitely annoying after working hard to make an answer the best I could before heading to work.

Comment: Note for any new readers stumbling across this old Q&A: the automatic conversion of posts to community wiki due to too many edits, as mentioned here, [was removed in 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228947). The only ways in which a question or an answer can now become a community wiki are described in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741).