# Reputation history stuck at yesterday after association bonus on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, association-bonus

After I got my association bonus yesterday, my reputation stopped increasing.

With the bonus 100 rep, I got a total of 165 reputation yesterday. And today I wrote some answers and I got 1 up-vote from an answer and 2 up-votes + accept. But they did not increase my reputation, and I did not even get any notification.

The reputation history in my profile from today is empty. I did not exceed the 200 reputation limit yesterday. What is the problem that I missed? Why did I not get any notification for my accepted answer and why did I not get any reputation from that answer?

Comment: I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Let me try my change again with editing

Comment: Your posts got no votes. Do you expect reputation changes when no votes took place? I see votes today on [one answer by you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46254777/1583) - but for some reason you marked it as "community wiki", meaning no reputation will be received for the votes on it.

Comment: ​@ssovukluk I suggested an edit. I assume you mean "nothing" and not "anything". If that's the case, I understand your question a bit better.

Comment: @DonaldDuck you edit was rejected by system but i copied it. I hope it is okay

Comment: @Oded Well i do not remember i enabled that option? Is it only for that answer or general?

Comment: There's a checkbox near the answer edit box - you must have checked it (you can go back to edit the answer to uncheck it).

Comment: @Oded there is no checkbox near answer when i edit it again. But i found this question https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203603/why-does-stack-overflow-make-all-my-answers-community-wiki   after a certain edits it is converted into CW automatically? Should i call a moderator?

Comment: @Oded I even searched the edit page for wiki, it found nothing.

Comment: @ssovukluk - no, that doesn't happen anymore. There is a checkbox, just under, to the right of the answer edit box. The edit history of the post shows you have changed it to CW in your second revision. You should be able to undo that. If you cannot, do you want me to do so?

Comment: @Oded Help center and faq say only a moderator can uncheck the community wiki. There should be moderator intervention if the OP wants the rep.

Comment: @Sinister - sure, but the OP needs to ask for that to happen first.

Comment: It should also be noted that even when the CW is removed, reputation is not restored to the OP. Only for votes *following* the removal, @Sinister

Comment: I've acted on your flag on the post and removed the CW status from it. Any votes you get on it from now on will count towards your reputation.

Comment: @Oded Thank you for your interest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one upvote you got is already recorded yesterday and is showing in the reputation activity.

The post is converted to a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) in revision 2.

The accepted answer is a community wiki. Voting on that answer do not effect your reputation.

From [What are community posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)

> - *Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any user's reputation*.
> - *Accepting an answer marked as community wiki does not affect its original author's reputation*, and does not give +2 to the question author.

Only a moderator can remove the community wiki status.