# Is there an unintended loophole regarding the fact that edits push a post to the frontpage?

Tags: discussion, edits, homepage

Now, I must preface this by saying that I am a karma-collector. I feel *terrible* divulging this sort of information... but I think that fair is fair.

The issue regards the fact that I can trivially edit an old question, and it will be bounced to the front page again (assuming, of course, that it is above -8 votes).

But isn't this slightly unfair? I might go into an old question, change the wording or punctuation.. and suddenly I get front-page coverage.

[image]

Now, the front page is valuable real estate. I'm not sure this is a big issue, but it might need revisiting.

Comment: No, this is not a *unintended* loophole. That said, there *is* a rate limiting measure to keep you from doing this too often: [Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179901/)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - ah that is interesting - thanks very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the behaviour is as intended.

Drawing attention to edited questions is *good* as it gives the community an opportunity to see nefarious edits as well as good ones.

There *is* a limit to the number of edits you should make, however; if you edit the post more than 10 times (not counting grace-period edits) it becomes a [Community Wiki post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). CW posts no longer earn you reputation when upvoted.

See [Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179901/why-does-repeated-editing-by-same-user-lead-to-community-wiki)