# My question was made community wiki

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, community-wiki

My question [FMA3 in GCC: how to enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001388/fma3-in-gcc-how-to-enable) was made community wiki. Why was this done?

I guess it was done because I made more than 10 edits? Almost all of the those edits were to fix typos. Is it possible to have my question returned to me?

I just discovered that several more of my posts have become community wiki such 
as

- [Calculating matrix product is much slower with SSE than with straight-forward-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435621/calculating-matrix-product-is-much-slower-with-sse-than-with-straight-forward-al/20440362#20440362)
- [Quickly count number of zero-valued bytes in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927710/quickly-count-number-of-zero-valued-bytes-in-an-array/20933337#20933337)

How about sending an automated message to the inbox saying your answer/question has been made a community wiki due to editing it 10 times along with an explanation as to why this is done.

Comment: You can flag>other and request the CW be removed, but it will only be reverted if the majority of the edits are substantial. This is to discourage repeated editing just to bump the question

Comment: @RichardTingle The majority of the edits are *not* substantial though.

Comment: @Servy then the OP may be in trouble here

Comment: Review your question for typos *before* posting.

Comment: Related: [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203616) and [Why does repeated editing by same user lead to community wiki?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179901)

Comment: you say "almost all those edits were for typos" but they're not, you're having a conversation with answerers in the question. Please don't do that. Comment on their answers saying why they don't work. The question is supposed to be a question, not an evolving solution to the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't OPs get a warning the first time?  I was not even aware of this.  I made those edits to make the question more clear for others.  If I had know this I would have left it as is and it would have been worse.

Comment: @Zboson Yeah, I think I saw a feature request for a warning of some sort.

Comment: The question has not been answered.  A work around was found.  But nobody has answered why GCC has not coverted my code to FMA instructions without me having to do it myself (with intrinsics).

Comment: Half way down the question I wrote in bold " I'm not sure why the compiler won't do this for me".  Nobody has explained this.

Comment: @ZBoson again, whether your question was answered is an entirely seperate matter. Use a bounty to attract attention,  reply to answers on the answers, only edit the question to clarify it

Comment: @Zboson It's not like the world is ending because the question is CW.  I could certainly see a warning if something really significant was happening, like it being closed/deleted/locked just because of edits, but it's only being made CW.  Now you know not to make lots of trivial edits, so it's fine.

Comment: @Zboson if you want to change the functionality of CW, I suggest you create a new question and propose such a feature.  Editing a feature request into your discussion question to change the question from "why did this happen" to "I think the system needs to notify me" is not going to get any attention from anyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is right in the revision history:

> [made Community Wiki by Z boson editing at least 10 times]

When a post has been edited by the same user 10 times it is made CW.

You should avoid making so many small edits over a long period of time.  Try to go through the post just a few times and make more significant improvements.

Comment: Or possibly even go through the question *before* posting and clearing out all the small things. Especially with programming questions, that can solve the question before it's even posted.

Comment: Did you read the question?  I hardly think there was a clear solution.  In fact it has not really been answered.  I still don't know why the compiler does not do the FMA itself as I have been told it should.

Comment: @Zboson whether the (linked) question was answered is hardly the point. If you need to draw attention to it use a bounty

Comment: I don't see the "Made Community Wiki" reference.  Where is it in the revision history?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe the reference to CW conversion in the revision history gets removed when the CW is removed.  I can't remember where I read that, but I believe I saw that in a bug report or a comment somewhere.

Comment: @Servy I see the cw has been removed. I suppose this means the limit for getting these approved is "not repeatedly inserting and removing a single letter". Im not sure I'm wildly happy with that

Comment: What is a "long period of time" I asked this question yesterday?

Comment: @RichardTingle I agree, this post most certainly should have stayed CW.  [It even seems clear](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215695/my-question-was-made-community-wiki/215697?noredirect=1#comment697125_215695) that the *intent* was to bump the post; the CW-ing was *specifically* added to combat this.

Comment: What does "bump the post" mean?  And why would editing single letters typos do this?

Comment: @Zboson In this context, "long period of time" means longer than the 5 minute grace period.  Were all of the edits made right away, within just a few minutes, it wouldn't mean new revisions.  The fact that you manged to make 10 full edits in that period of time is a very strong indication that something is wrong.  When there are 10 legitimate edits made to a question it usually takes months.  I don't see a need for you to have made more than 2-3 edits to that question.

Comment: @Zboson It refers to the fact that when viewing questions by activity, (edits being a type of activity) editing a post moves it to the top of the list.

Comment: Okay, now I understand.  I was not aware of that.