# Allow new members to make trivial edit suggestions if they judge other trivial edit suggestions

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

If we're worried about new members making trivial edits that take up the time of more important people, why don't we let them judge them themselves? Something like you get the right to suggest 5 edits for every 10 you judge correctly.

[[image: xkcd/810]

<sup>And what about all the people who won't be able to join the community because they're terrible at making helpful and constructive co-- ... oh.</sup>](http://xkcd.com/810/)

Answer (score 7):

So when you have a baby that needs parenting, the solution is to ... get another baby to raise the first baby?

I can't see any way this could go wrong!

Comment: Don't you know it's cheaper by the dozen?

Comment: The analogy isn't perfect. For one thing these are often highly qualified professionals who are simply arriving at our site for the first time. Many are only nOObs in the sense that they aren't familiar with our community. That doesn't make them incompetent.  Not that I agree with the suggestion. I'd don't think it would be good to have two people with no experience with the site be able to approve edits. It might be acceptable to gain the "solo" edit privilege earlier based on a track record of accepted edits rather than rep, though. I realize that it sort of works this way now but slowly.

Comment: Just cuz s0me1 has no high rep on one SE site doesn't mean they don't haz glue about spelling and stuff

Comment: How did this site ever get started?

Answer (score 1):

I see this could be useful, especially in connection with the request [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483/146482). I don't want a spelling police, but I myself am grateful if someone fixes my English when it sounds weird.