# Block "problems" as well as just "problem" in question titles

Tags: feature-request, title, quality-filter

The quality filter is already blocking "problem" in question title on Stack Overflow. All good and running well for long time.

However it does allow the word "problems" and honestly, can't see the point in this.

[Here is one example of misusing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12321198/problems-with-apostrophe) (already corrected, see [revisions list](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12321198/revisions)), <strike>surely there are hundreds every day</strike>.

[Quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=title:problems) for "problems" in question title revealed it's not hunderds, maybe around 20-30 every day but still, would like even those to be titled properly.

Either block both forms of the word or remove this filter altogether.

Comment: I'm not so sure about this title filter to begin with. It's a [prblm](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aprblm)..no, [problam](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aproblam)..wait, [problm](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aproblm)...ah, [porblem](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aporblem)... wait, how do you write that again? ;)

Comment: @Bart I agree but it's not related - this filter is currently a fact. :/

Comment: This was more a response to your "or remove the filter altogether". But you're right. If it stays in place, "problems" should be added for the sake of consistency.

Comment: related: ["Problem" word filter can be circumvented in a search engine compatible way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122172/problem-word-filter-can-be-circumvented-in-a-search-engine-compatible-way)