# On minor sites, would it be possible to implement a 'hide from the front page' feature for edits?

Tags: feature-request, edits, question-lists, homepage

On [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) there are frequent complaints about waves of edits removing interesting new content from the 'front page', which is used by many to track the site's activity. Would it be possible to implement a checkbox to hide an edit from the 'front page' on minor sites such as Travel.SE?  Obviously it should only be available for high-rep users (10k could be a nice limit) to avoid abuse.

The situation there is different from the discussed [Stack Overflow feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers) since the site gets 20-30 new questions per day and the edit waves are *a lot* more noticeable.

Comment: What might be better would be to have the Moderators have an option to edit without flooding the front page.

Answer (score 4):

Showing edits has a purpose: getting eyes on them to validate if the edit is correct or not and if there should be any action (flagging for example).

If you are not interested in edits, just open the [newest view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), which will not show edits.

Comment: The newest view does not show late answers, that's why I -1 your A.

Comment: Then come with another solution that doesn't do harm to the overall quality of the sites.

Comment: Good point, please see [my suggestion to create a tab that shows questions which are either new or have received recent answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291499/327953)