# Site view with recently active questions & answers but excluding edits!

Tags: feature-request, edits, question-lists

## Feature Request

In the **Questions** view of a site, add a tab/option to view **questions that are either new or have received new answers**, i.e. questions that have new content beyond edits.

## Background

Over on [Travel SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/) we have some users that are very actively editing old questions, even for minor edits. [It's a hot topic](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4309/32134) and not topic of this request, however [many](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35649232#35649232) [users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35558830#35558830) are [bothered](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35558830#35558830).
A solution would be [not to see minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/26483/327953) edits [but suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291483/327953) in this direction have [not been received well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/26496/327953) (IMHO rightfully so) because of accountability. [Some people suggest](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4327/32134) [viewing the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/291484/327953) [newest questions tab](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest), but while this does not show edits, it does only show new questions but not late answers, a feature I find essential.

## Feature Description

I want a tab under questions that shows questions which are either

- newly asked questions

or

- questions that have recently received an answer,

sorted by the time passed since the last of these two events. Edits to questions or answers shall be explicitly excluded to move up questions on these list. This would be identical to the [start page](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions) behavior minus edits (and modulo deleted answers maybe?).