# Who is notified when I comment?

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

I read the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) and [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28042/be-notified-when-someone-leaves-a-comment-that-is-a-direct-response-to-my-commen) on this topic, and the rules there do not seem correct.  I [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612386/quick-question-about-number-of-positive-summands-in-a-sum-of-p-adic-integers?noredirect=1#comment3286619_1612386) an answer as a comment, and the owner thanked me without citing @Alex, and I got his comment as a notification.  I then replied, and he replied (without citing me again), and I got his comment again.

What are the full rules of who gets notified on comments?  I would like to avoid writing @Username whenever they would get my comment anyways.

Comment: "The author of the post". It really can't be more clear than that.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258812/why-are-we-not-notified-when-new-comments-appear-after-we-leave-a-comment

Comment: But I am not the author of the post, and I was notified.

Comment: @nicael Thanks, that answers my question.  Should I update the FAQ thread to reflect that, or should I leave that for the big guns?

Comment: You said "posted an answer". You should have said "the answer was converted to comment".

Comment: @ShadowWizard Wrong again.  I cited that thread in my post, saying that the information there was not correct.

Comment: I meant, I posted an answer (to his question) as a comment.

Comment: That is not relevant. Anyway it is already in the FAQ you linked to: *Note if a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is not included*

Comment: Lol, but the FAQ actually appears to include it - "Note if a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person is also notified if @name is not included."

Comment: Hmm, thanks, I missed that.