# Usernames ending in "json" cause trouble

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, json

When you visit a user's profile page, the actual username in the URL isn't supposed to matter. For example, all these URLs go to the same place:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-the-dragon
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1

However, if your username happens to end in the letters `json`, your profile page gets screwed up:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeffendinginjson

Comment: No actual file names, and still the ghost of file extensions as meta-data haunts us...

Comment: Predicted fix: Disallow usernames ending in `json`

Comment: Methinks that someone has been playing with a route to let people download data as JSON.  Might want to adjust the regex in that routing constraint.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Wouldn't it be funny if he just forgot to escape the dot?

Comment: @ベレアー アダム why do you hate me and Martin Jajson? http://es-es.facebook.com/mjajson

Comment: @json: I don't hate you, I'm merely the harbinger of your doom.

Comment: This receives Pollyanna's coveted **LOL OF THE DAY** seal.  Congratulations.

Comment: Badge request for lol-of-the-day in 3... 2... 1...

Comment: Are the argonauts ok?

Answer (score 11):

I'm sorry, I won't do it again.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRGH!

Comment: Now you username has history like mine... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post/37094#37094

Comment: @downvoter My name changes have always had some kind of history ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/26518#26518

Comment: You won't do it for another 30 days, you mean.

Answer (score 4):

Also broken: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/web.config

Comment: ...and that's probably a good thing.

Comment: ...but why that *specific* error?

Comment: totally unrelated bug

Comment: `web.config` is actually an IIS config file to control web access to the folder in question. It's roughly the same as `.htaccess` is for Apache HTTPD. If it was public accessible, it might leak sensitive information about for example folders, configs, patterns, etc, we shouldn't know about. So that it errors is only good.