# Usernames ending in ".aspx" or ".asax" cause a 404

Tags: support

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeffendingin.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeffendingin.asax

Maybe this is something to not bother with, but I thought of it because [Usernames ending in Json Cause Trouble](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44461/usernames-ending-in-json-cause-trouble) was fixed.

Bonus: The two 404s are different!

Comment: Interesting. Ending with [.aspx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeffendingin.aspx) produces a 404, ending with [.asax](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeffendingin.asax) produces an XML parser error, and ending with [.asmx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeffendingin.asmx) takes you to the right page!

Comment: @Jon: Funny, .asax isn't giving me an XML parser error.

Comment: With second link I got a WSOD.

Comment: The parsing error thing appears to be client-side (Firefox). If I view source on the page, it's completely empty. @kia

Comment: Is there a username that this actually fits?  Not seeing one in search.

Comment: Not just usernames.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62865/usernames-ending-in-aspx-or-asax-cause-a-404.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a bug, because the dot in the name will be replaced by a "-" in the link to his profile.

Example : Add ".aspx" to your name.