# Do down-voters get my request for comment comments?

Tags: support, down-votes, notifications

I recently posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463145/where-do-i-handle-aggregateexception-when-cancelling-net-tasks) that I put significant effort into.  The problem I was having was complex, and I posted a significant amount of code.  I included links to pages that I tried using, and searched S.O. for a good .5-1.0 hour before posting.

I was downvoted after 45 minutes of waiting for an answer without any explanation.  I posted a comment asking for clarification, but didn't get any.

My question is: Do down-voters actually *get* my requests for clarification?  I really want a good answer, and if my question is bad I want to fix it. Down votes just decrease the chance that anyone will look at it.

Comment: If http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463145/where-do-i-handle-aggregateexception-when-cancelling-net-tasks was the question, I couln't see anything wrong with it. But its not my main area.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.  Strange huh? (Wish someone knew what was up with that).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They will not see your request for clarification unless they come back to the question on their own (there's no notification at the moment for this)

Comment: Thanks Juan, is such notification likely to ever show up?

Comment: @cpf, there are some requests for that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090/feature-request-downvoter-sends-a-notification-to-all-downvoters-for-your-post and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-ch

Comment: Great! Thanks.  +1 (Were I allowed to! :) )

Comment: Now that I'm allowed to, +1 for real.