# What should we do about users adding nonsense to question just to meet quality standards?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

I just came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/313265/ssl-vpn-client) on Super User. The user wanted a SSL VPN client and proceeded to ask: "Is there any (free) SSL VPN Client for Windows?" obviously this question is too short and quality standards algorithm picked it up and told him to add some more details (as it should).

Instead of adding pertinent information like specific OS (what version of windows?) and what he is connecting to at the other end he just copy and pasted the quality standards message into the question. What should we do about this? Should I edit it out? Voted to close? Flag for mod attention? Ignore it? Or leave a comment like I did?

In this instance I voted to close and commented because it may be a dupe of the other VPN question (no details so it's hard to tell).

I added this question on MSO since this is an issue that could affect any site within the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Since I posted this a mod came along and closed it as a dupe... however if it wasn't a dupe how should I have proceeded?

Comment: Isn't that nice of him? He was *informing* you that his post didn't meet the minimum quality bar and needed to be deleted. I almost wish **more** users did this.

Comment: I do something similar with comments regularly. I usually use ...... for padding though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To repeat what @Robert & @MichaelMrozek mentioned, edit the crap out, downvote it, leave a comment mentioning rather than filling *further reading* and *related question* info, the user  might want to add details which will make someone read the *current* question.

And oh, don't forget to Vote To Close / Flag it for closing as Not a Real Question.

<sub><sub>FTR It's not the first time the particular user has done that.</sub></sub>

Comment: Thanks Sathya... leading by example as always.

Comment: Seems like this user does it all the time, but not to fool the filters.  [This is a very good question](http://superuser.com/questions/303365/what-does-legacy-usb-mouse-support-in-a-bios-mean) where he has a "see also" section.  I'm sure he didn't need that to get his question submitted.

Comment: @Won't Ah yes, I should have been clear - he doesn't do it to beat the filters, it's his posting "style"

Comment: A "see also" section *could* potentially be helpful (unless it's an exact copy and paste from the "Related" sidebar, I suppose), but a giant screenshot of the "This post is not good enough" message is never going to be helpful.

Answer (score 15):

The usual close, downvote, edit and delete mechanisms should be adequate for handling any questions that get by the filter.

Always downvote such questions; that gets the poster a little closer to a question ban.

Comment: I have no idea why I didn't think of downvoting... Probably should have just treated it as any other bad question.

Comment: @Kyle: If it helps, I recommend frowning *very deeply*, then clicking the down vote button more emphatically than otherwise.

Comment: @camccan: If it helps, I laughed while clicking the up vote on your comment.

Comment: I like this, but I forsee it leading to lots of "why was this downvoted?" comments on borderline posts after editing occurs. How do we deal with that side effect?

Comment: Maybe we should educate the user instead of punishing him.

Comment: @Popular: I think the comment that was left on [his post](http://superuser.com/questions/313265/ssl-vpn-client) solves that problem.

Comment: @Lance: This user has done this before.  He knows what he is doing.

Comment: @Pop: [Flag them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment/74568#74568). Those comments are nothing but noise.

Comment: @Aarobot and Robert, the comments themselves aren't as bad as the incorrect feeling of "other users on this site are stupid and don't know how to vote" that they represent (and erroneously instill before they get deleted). Or the "compensation upvoting" that they may cause. I guess comments like the one Robert linked to should be sufficient to handle things.

Answer (score 6):

Certainly edit it out; leaving that in makes the post look terrible. If the post is bad without it, downvote/close it as well, like any other post. Personally I think those people should be suspended, but that's up to the mods on your site; I'd at least flag it so they're aware the user is pulling nonsense like that

Answer (score 5):

As well as editing out the rubbish and frowning with stern disapproval, you might also consider leaving a comment to the effect that the system is suggesting more detail *for a reason* and that they should take its advice under consideration in the future, since their current behavior is an express ticket to question ban city.

Note that even in the unlikely scenario that the question really is complete, well-formed, and of acceptable quality despite being too short, a word of warning about consequences remains helpful and polite.

Answer (score 0):

Down vote and vote to close, **but do not edit it out**. If you edit it out, the question will not get as many down votes, and it is less likely the user will be banned.

Flagging as well could be useful, as the moderators may be able to ban the user.