# What do you do if you have only a question title?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, title

And no need to fill in the question body? Do you just repeat the title in the body?

Comment: On what site? I can't think of a site or question which you wouldn't ever want or need to expand on a little  bit. People cannot read your mind or know what your exact issue is, so you need to explain. Even this question here, your title arguably asks everything you need to know, but the extra info you provided clarifies *exactly* what you mean and removes ambiguity.

Comment: I don't think the specific site really matters for this question to be answerable. On several sites I've come across users repeating only their title's question in the body, adding nothing more.

Comment: Related: [Should "Title Says It All" questions be edited or closed?](/q/119410) (has some quite useful discussion)

Answer (score 16):

Example?

As a general rule, if all you have is a title, you're asking wrong.

What's the context for your question? Is there really no more detail you can add that would make your question clearer and easier to answer?

Answer (score 8):

If your question title, which is used to summarize the contents of your question body, is identical to it, then I would suggest that you need to think harder about what it is you want to ask and what you have done to research it prior to asking.

Otherwise it is hard to see how such a question would avoid people hovering over the downvote button and seeing the advice to use it "when this question does not show any research effort".

[image]

I always suggest that on any Stack Exchange site a minimum length question (or answer) should normally be thought of as being "about a paragraph".

Comment: Example:  [How can I view all the messages I posted in a Slack channel?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/117076/18147). I don't see the point in saying "I tried to Google the answer  but didn't find  any" in the question details just for the sake of writing something.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt In that question you say what you want to do, but not what you've tried or where you're stuck.  Since it shows no research effort into trying to answer your own question I think on most SE sites such a brief question would risk downvotes.  With that near empty extra sentence I think it would also risk downvotes.

Comment: @PolyGeo But that question wasn't even downvoted, but upvoted like 30 times. Also, webapps.se doesn't [require research](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/does-web-apps-stack-exchange-require-research)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if the OP only has a "question title", they might actually have a "seed question" in the sense of something to start searching the site and researching according to the site scope and audience.

If they don't have idea about where to start, this question title / seed question might work as a conversation starter for a discussion in the per-site Meta or as an ice-breaker in one of the site's chatrooms, but regarding posting a question on the main site, I think that all the sites will encourage users to provide brief, but complete context.

I participate mostly on sites related to computers ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour), and [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)). These sites have thousands of questions, and there is a lot of content available on the web, digital and brick and mortar libraries. Most of the questions that I have reviewed are related to stuff that have some canonical resources about theory, from market researchers, from vendors for different audiences like developers, administrators, trainers, end-users or addressed to emerging audiences.

Considering the above, I think that it's not really too hard to include a description of what was found in the site and the basic reference source in the question body, i.e., Gmail Help Center for questions about using Gmail, and why it didn't meet their needs.

The specifics might vary from site to site or even from tag to tag, so specifics should be better to be discussed in the corresponding per-site meta.

One of the posts including general guidance, [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), for this specific case is [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/289691).

---

Note:

Regarding this question in Meta SE, five years before it was asked it was requested ["Title-only" questions (i.e., questions without body) should be allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66119/289691) (from 2010). This was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

#### Other related

- [What can I do when getting “This question body does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92074/289691) from 2011
- [What should we do about users adding nonsense to question just to meet quality standards?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99271/289691) from 2011
- [What should I write in the question body if the title already explains everything?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145019/289691) from 2012
- [Is it time to tighten up the question quality filter?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174097/289691) from 2013
- [Title and question body are the same](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193632/289691) from 2013

---

### Related questions from some per-site metas

#### Meta Arqade

- [What is the ideal body for simple unambiguous one-liner questions?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14624/115285) from 2019

#### Meta Aviation

- [Should we close questions for not doing research?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1551) from 2015

#### Meta Ethereum

- [How to deal with users spamming one-line questions and answers?](https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com/q/100) from 2016

#### Meta Stack Overflow

- [What's unclear about this question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272174/1595451) from 2014
- [Should I repeat the title in the question body?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278902/1595451) from 2014
- [Old highly upvoted questions that don't follow current SO standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306273/1595451) from 2015
- [Should my reaction be any different when title=post content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398556/1595451) from 2020
- [Is there a minimum length to consider a question as 'a good one'?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419760/1595451) from 2022

#### Meta Raspberry Pi

- [How is this question too broad?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/802) from 2016

#### Meta Unix & Linux

- [Asking a short question triggers the quality filter](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2619) from 2013