# Is there something similar to the quality filter for edits made by the OP?

Tags: discussion, edits, question-quality, quality-filter, grace-period

I have found some recent questions that have by-passed the quality filter and doesn't show any revision. My guess is that the OP found a way to by-pass the quality filter in order to get their question posted then edited the question.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of automatic question quality enforcement for edits made by the OP that might be failing or should be improved.

Related

- [What should we do about users adding nonsense to question just to meet quality standards?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99271/289691) (discussion from 2011)
- [Add recursive defenses to the quality standards](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111577/289691) (feature request without status tag from 2011)
- [Add attempts to game the "quality standards" filter to the Low Quality queue for review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181332/289691) (feature request without status tag from 2013)

Comment: Is this specific to [so]? Are you talking about the LQ review queue?

Comment: @Werner This is something relating to all sites. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-this-question-body-does-not-meet-our-quality-standar

Comment: (You can accept your own answer. This will prevent bumps by the "Community" user.)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I will wait a bit (I think one more month) before accepting my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there isn't something similar to the quality filter for edits made by the OP, but there are some related feature requests:

- [What can we do to stop spammers from exploiting the grace period?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322435/289691)

  This is a discussion and also a feature request that refers to spammers exploiting the grace period.
- [End the edit grace period upon two or more spam/rude flags being raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307637/289691)

  This other feature request suggests a solution based on span / rude-abusive flags.

In this case, I was not thinking specifically on spammers / bullies, but on OPs posting the questions with the same body as the title.