# Is it bad to ask in the comments why you got down voted on an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it now discouraged to ask for reasons for downvotes as a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74559/is-it-now-discouraged-to-ask-for-reasons-for-downvotes-as-a-comment)

Is it bad to ask in the comments why you got down voted on an answer?

Just wondering because I would like to get better at answering questions, and getting down voted without a reason makes we wonder what I did wrong.

Comment: @antisanity - Just leave a polite comment asking for clarification. You don't need the downvoter to tell you why your post got downvoted. In most cases, it will be clear to many passerbys and the feedback will still give you an opportunity to edit and fix your post.

Comment: @antisanity - Why? You'll just get tons of "I don't like this answer" comments. (With some variations :-)