# Is there any mechanism to deter users from unnecessarily messing with user points?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, privileges, moderation, users

I had noticed that some users uses their right to vote up and down a question unnecessarily.

I was a victim of such some months back, had to abandon my account for a new one because of some, some, some people... really annoying.

Some of them even down vote a question just because they think it is too easy, which leaves me wondering if there were born with whatever knowledge they think they have.

As a matter of fact, being a confirmation, some people will down vote this question. (If you are one of them, please be helpful as to give a reason for your action)

I was hoping SE would implement an appeal button where more superior members would re-evaluate such cases.

Comment: Regarding your second-to-last paragraph, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta "Voting is different on Meta".

Comment: I didn't vote but most likely reason for downvotes on this question is that [Tim lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)

Comment: I downvoted because I disagree with what you suggest, plus people are free to vote in whatever way they want. Take this away, and you better close Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a particular user is targeting you with up or down votes, the system [does have safeguards to nullify that targeted voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).

Beyond that, individual votes cast against individual posts are completely up to the discretion of the voter. They can vote however they want, and voting is anonymous by design. None of us can know what a voter is thinking, nor do we have the right to tell them how to vote or "correct" their votes afterward.

In general, good and/or useful content gets voted up, and bad or incorrect content gets voted down. Occasionally, you get inexplicable up or down votes, but that's the fun of dealing with humans. I, for one, would not trust a system where any vote of mine could be determined to be "incorrect" and overruled by a cabal of higher-reputation users.

Only when one person is clearly being targeted by another does voting become worth nullifying, and even then only in more severe cases.