# Cross-site management of favorite and ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags, cross-site-tags

I find the favorite and ignored tags a very useful feature, and I use many of the same tags for several different subforums. The problem is that tags are usually not added in bulk, but as I browse on the fly. So adding just a single favorite tag becomes a tedious process of clicking through pages. Keeping track of what tags are saved for what subforums becomes confusing.

Tags should be able to be saved for the specific sub-site of Stack Exchange, or exported to all other sites, analogous to the “User Profile → Edit Profile & Settings → Edit Profile” page. [image: screenshot]

The favorite/ignored tags could be split up into two sections: one for the current site, and the other for all sites.

(A related question was split from this one and posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268125).)

Comment: Tim Post [lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) again.

Comment: Why would I want to do this cross-site? Tags don't have much meaning cross-site and neither do favourites. This does seem like two ideas in one a) cross-site tags and b) better tag management. If you split them up you might find people like b) even though they dislike a)

Comment: Agree with Robert. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: @RobertLongson My personal reason is to hide all OS or IDE specific questions (and these kinds of questions are common in many subforums), which is a pain to maintain for 5-10 different sites. Adding a single ignored tag suddenly becomes a clickfest with waiting for a lot of pages to load.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yes, you’re right, it is a rather broad question. I’ll split it up into two different ones.

Comment: Please do so and ping me when you are done. Will check if I can retract my close vote.

Comment: @svenper That's all very well if you only frequent programming sites but [tag:apple] on Stack Overflow does not mean the same as on Seasoned Advice.

Comment: @Robert but what if I use a robotic apple for my programming experiments? ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman The question is now updated, focusing on the ‘cross-site’ question. The ‘advanced management’ question is now live [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268125).

Answer (score 2):

Tags are not always exchangeable between sites. Often they aren't. Apple has a different meaning across sites and so for gallery, picture, etc.

If you take that into account, copying tags around isn't that useful. I think it is even harder to keep track of all the added tags you actually didn't want to. Personally, I have a handful of tags I am interested in, and I don't see the point in making an entire system out of this for such a little gain.

Comment: Valid points, though the most prominent subforums focus on programming and system administration, which share many similar tags.

The last paragraph of my question brings up the possibility of two sections of tags: one for site-specific ones, and another for global ones.

Comment: But how many of them do you have? 10? 20? That is quite manageable without all this.

Comment: I currently have a total of 30 (constantly growing), but actually this question was inspired by re-creating all of my tags after discovering that wildcards were available. Without wildcards I had somewhere between 50–100 tags, which is significantly less manageable.

I suggest clarification on using wildcards in my [other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268125).

Keep in mind also that I am a new user, so I may have had a bit more concentrated account management than others. But in order to make these forums more attractive, new users should have simple management.

Answer (score 0):

This is already possible, kind of,  via https://stackexchange.com/ which contains [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters).

You can create new filter, and choose a tag then "all sites" - you will get the top 100 questions with that tag, cross site.

For example: [apples](https://stackexchange.com/filters/207967/apples).

Not 100% what you ask for,  but closest we will get, and good enough in my opinion.