# Advanced favorite and ignored tags management

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, ignored-tags

Currently the management of favorite and ignored tags is clunky and [error-prone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30827/confirm-dialog-when-an-interesting-or-ignored-tag-is-to-be-deleted). Deletion of several tags at once requires an unnecessary amount of random mouse movement, which could be accomplished instead via keyboard actions.

I propose the following mutually independent changes:

1. The tags are sorted in a list, where tags can be browsed with the arrow keys and selected individually or in groups by toggling the ‘manage’ state of a tag with <kbd>Space</kbd>, a <kbd>^</kbd>-click or a <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click, e.g. like the country selection list [here](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist).

   Alternatively the ‘manage’ state could be toggled by <kbd>Space</kbd> or a simple left click.

   Actions such as removal or rearrangement of the selected tags would be performed via a menu.
2. Tags can be rearranged by drag-and-drop.
3. Tags can be sorted via a separate menu.
4. Tags can be edited in plain text, separated by newlines, commas or spaces.
5. There should be a notice that wildcards (`*`) are accepted in tags.

(Originally posted [Cross-site management of favorite and ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268121) but question split up and moved here for narrowing down the topic.)

Answer (score 1):

> The tags are sorted in a list, where tags can be browsed with the arrow keys and selected individually or in groups

Individually? Then click on the tag itself. If in groups, what is the purpose to do so? The only reason I see is to move between "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags" and to delete the selected tags. No need here. It would also be easier to make checkboxes so you can select the tags easier rather than using arrow keys (you might use them to go up and down a page).

> Tags can be rearranged by drag-and-drop.

Can't find a good reason why. No need here since I don't personally think you chose that many tags...

> Tags can be sorted via a separate menu.

I like where the tags are being managed in the right hand side of the page. It's easily accessible and also really easy to use. Why waste time using another window when you can control it from a nice section devoted to tags?

> Tags can be edited in plain text, separated by newlines, commas or spaces.

No no no! It would seriously look terrible (no offense intended) and ruin the look of the oval-shaped tags. Even some are even color-coded to distinguish different pre-set groups of tags (the status- series, etc.)

> There should be a notice that wildcards (*) are accepted in tags.

Let's add that into the Help Center in the page where tag creation rules are discussed shall we?