# Could someone analyse my SO question is getting downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

First, is there some place to validate why your questions are marked or downvoted? Second, I've just written this question [How to migrate parts from one active database to another active database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412703/how-to-migrate-parts-from-one-active-database-to-another-active-database) but it automatically had a downvote I don't know why, who did it and what did I do wrong?

Comment: Do we really need to discuss a single downvote? For all we know, [Tim lost his keys again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/162704)...

Comment: Down votes are only automatically placed when someone raises a spam or offensive flag. Otherwise your question was down voted by a user.

Comment: Yannis sorry did know it was such a big issue and @angussidney could I see why or when someone did raise the spam or offensive flag?

Answer (score 4):

I'd bet the key sentence is

> What's the best solution for doing this?

which makes your question primarily opinion based. This is a close reason on Stack Overflow.

I currently can't see if there's a close vote raised on your question, but close and down votes are often placed along.

Comment: Let me help you out here: There are no close votes casted when I just visited that question. Besides POB I could also argue it being rather broad.

Comment: @rene Thanks for clarification. Anyways the fact of that sentence and asking very unspecific without anything tried could well be the reason for the downvote.

Comment: Why I can't ask a primarily opinion based question? And I think more people could benefit from my question it's a really general question, not application or programming language specific.

Comment: @0x1ad2 You can read more about SO's policies for on-topic questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).