# Hidden Negitive Reputation Score

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, account-suspension, abandonment

With all the down voting going on why not have the number next to your profile picture also reflect negative reputation that people including you can't see? Why isn't there a box where they can put why they down voted only you can see?

I notice even if I have a positive reputation after a long year long suspension I still have to be very careful not to get flagged. It is not like when you first start where you can make a few mistakes and get a day or week. If you get suspended it is for another year for any mistake you make. I am trying to fix my early errors but only receive more down votes or something that keeps me in a perpetual state of bans and suspensions. I just want to start fresh.

Comment: You are completely welcome to create memes explaining downvotes. The other part of your question is a duplicate.

Comment: Why? You could just read the reasons from the downvote tooltip. *This question does not show any research effort...* does not need to be repeated 6 or more times.

Comment: Tim Post [lost his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397) again.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it separately instead of editing an old question into a different question.

Comment: The first revisions of your question asked why users can’t have negative reputation, and asserted that downvotes should require explanations.  The question now seems to be discussing the difficulty of recovering from suspensions.  That looks like a very different question and should be asked separately, even if it is a follow-up question.

Comment: @NobodyNada I approved it. Feel free to help in any way you can. Thanks

Comment: If you’ve been suspended by a moderator on a site, you’ve received emails with details of exactly what you’re doing wrong and telling you to stop.  If you’re concerned about the quality of the questions you’re asking, your best bet is to read through the Help Center of the site you’re asking on and look at recent successful questions to learn what is expected from question authors.  If you’re unsure of why one of your questions has fallen short of the guidelines, you may ask about your question on that site’s meta.

Comment: @NobodyNada no help :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> With all the down voting going on why not have the number next to your profile picture also reflect negative reputation?

That means you can't answer nor ask, which will provide means to impossible comebacks to some users. Second, negative rep will would like we don't trust you at all, in fact we avoid you. That's not the message. So we have answer and question bans instead. Easier and less stressful for everyone.

> and have a comment box to be filled on why the down vote to help users better answers and questions?

Duplicate, duplicate, duplicate. Already been asked, never been solved completely.