# Protesting downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, tactical-downvoting, downvoted-questions

I saw a downvote on a question that I want to contest, because I think the question I asked, or somebody asked, isn't off-topic, too broad, etc., commonly the reason for downvoting.

Should we have some way to protest the downvote and bring it to the attention of the moderators, besides comments?

I posted this question because there might be cases of group tactical-downvoting involving a question that looked like it had an obvious answer, but there is an unexpected answer.

Or that the downvoter does not have a clear understanding of a question.

Or that the downvoter just wants reputation points or badges.

(I know it's probably debatable, but please indulge this question.)

Comment: I see this in the same vein as protesting someone else's vote for a presidential candidate at odds with your own political views: that guy's vote is not your concern. Make sure to vote in a way that reflects *your* opinions, and let consensus sort itself out. Votes (in political elections and StackExchange) are anonymous for a reason: how someone else voted is no one else's business.

Comment: As a note, downvotes on meta (particularly on Feature Request questions) show that a person *disagrees* with the request... It does not mean that the question was poorly phrased or researched the way it does on regular sites.

Comment: I re-tagged this as a discussion since you're essentially asking _should we have this?_ instead of _we definitely need this let's build it_. And, welcome to meta :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should 'drive by' downvoting be more effectively caught?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught)

Comment: Thank you @TimPost and gnat. Could not upvote your comments instead because of the reputation points going down down down. Haha. :)

Comment: I'll take that kind of irony over an up-vote _any_ day @Monica! Thanks for putting up with us :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are quite a few questions along the lines of "*Why was this question so heavily downvoted?*" to be found here and on Meta Stack Overflow. It does often come up when someone stumbles across something that received a resoundingly negative response, and the reasons for that response aren't immediately clear.

[Kate brings up the first important thing to check](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279198/50049), which is the revision history of the question. Look at the first revision, if you see stuff like:

- Text that is extremely difficult to read
- No example code posted, and the question makes you feel like there should be some
- The actual question is difficult to find - what's actually being asked here?
- Stuff in the 'related' list of questions in the sidebar look like they might have answers to the question, or you're sure you've seen this question asked differently at least a few times
- Even though the problem is clearly explained and seems interesting, the question seems like it's someone saying 'I can totally crowdsource this assignment'

..  then that's probably why it received the response that it did. While folks *can* take back a vote if the post was edited, there's no system in place to notify them of this - mostly because it would be a *huge* volume of notifications at the scale of Stack Overflow.

But, we do have some ideas of showing "You voted on this, and it changed" to users really interested in drilling into that. Until then, if you *really* think that something should have received a better reception and after doing some digging you're at a loss as to why it happened - you're welcome to ask on the meta site attached to the site you're using. Ask on the *per-site* meta, not here, because you need some topic knowledge to be able to answer well in most cases.

Just state why you found the question to be good (try to go beyond "it seemed okay to me", let folks know what they might have missed!) - explain why you feel that the question would be useful to have, and ask what else might be wrong with it. If it is a case of someone unfairly getting ganged up on by a clique of users, that will quickly come to light and be fixed.

In short we *do* have a system where someone can say "*what could possibly be wrong with this?*" - but take a few minutes to see what that might be prior to asking quite a few more eyes to have a look at it :)

Comment: Just be aware of the "meta effect" - if the majority of your per-site meta agree that the question deserves a downvote, it will get many more after you go to meta asking why it got some in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

No. Votes, whether they are up or down, are the expression of the opinion of one member of the community. Debating that is debating the opinion of the community as a whole.

If you disagree with the vote, just give your own vote and leave it there.

(I wonder if I would start a 'protesting upvotes' question... I have never seen such a question here)

Comment: Maybe you should, for the sake of discussion? :)

Answer (score 3):

Being "off-topic, too broad, etc" is reason for **close** voting, and if you have access to the review queues, you can vote "leave open" on such questions.

Downvoting is more subjective - and what's more, the issues that caused it (bad grammar, missing details, rude tone, appears to be a duplicate of a very commonly asked question) might be fixed by the time you see the question, making the original downvote right even if you don't think the question deserves one now. Or the question could be unchanged and you and that other voter could just disagree. It happens, the site is fine with it, there is no mechanism for taking other people's votes away or having to validate or approve them.