# Should a question be downvoted only because the downvoter thinks it is morally wrong?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

It looks like this answer may have been down voted because a commenter doesn't like that it's a violation of Amazon's terms of service. Is this a valid reason for a downvote?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43415661/242029

This question is not a duplicate as it lists a specific situation that is not mentioned in the question or any of the answers of its proposed duplicate. Changing the title to clarify the point.

The answer in here relates directly to the question that was asked, and did not relate to whether or not it will break Amazon's terms of service.  That's not really relevant to whether or not an HTTP request **can** be made from Node.js to Amazon. The downvote appears to be whether it should be made against the will of Amazon.

Comment: You can downvote or upvote for any reason you like as long as you don't target anyone and serially vote on their posts.

Comment: It would be amazing if we had a meta post about every single downvote.

Comment: You can't appeal a downvote; being able to do so would be impractical to the point of insanity.

Comment: Will we need a post about this post if it gets downvotes. We could be here a long while if we get recursive enough.

Comment: Ah, frick. I've lost my keys, sorry.

Comment: Anybody can up or downvote for any reason they want. If your post is helpful, it will accrue some upvotes to counter that. If not, it won't. The more important thing here is for you to get used to taking downvotes gracefully. If you continue to be active on these sites, you *will* receive more, this is just a fact of life. If the stress of this is too much to bear, then for your own [health and safety](https://www.google.com/search?q=effects%20of%20stress%20on%20the%20body) you either need to stop participating, or find a way to let it slide without skipping a beat.

Comment: I upvoted the question because the sky is blue.  So will you the author appeal my upvote?

Comment: @Ramhound no, I think we all need a way to [stop Tim from losing his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/165773)

Comment: I suspect many of the downvotes are for using the term "Best Practices".

Comment: @gnat I agree; But was using sarcasm to illustrate that when people upvotes because Tim lost his keys nobody complains about it.

Comment: @Ramhound at MSO one can find complaints about everything including even this: [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289607/839601) :)

Comment: Well, thanks for the sarcasm and down votes everyone, not only to this question, but six down votes to the answer itself.  I'm going to take @JasonC's advice and stop participating and/or let it slide.

Comment: Vandalizing (removing all the content of) your post is not how you get it deleted. All that will happen is the edit gets rolled back. There's really no reason to delete this post that I can see.

Comment: It is, in fact, a duplicate. The question and answer voting systems are the same, and also the nature of your specific answer is irrelevant. As explained in the link, votes cannot be appealed. Period. Note that duplicate links are helpful signposts for future readers and not a bad thing. Also, the above comment is correct, do not vandalize your posts. Not only does it not make sense, but you're hurting other people who may be able to find this question in the future, which isn't cool.

Comment: Ok, so the post is an uphelpful duplicate with (currently) nine down votes, and many, many sarcastic comments to accentuate that fact, but I can't remove it because it might be hurting people to not be able to find it?  How does that THAT make sense?

Comment: @nixkuroi 6 downvotes is -12 reputation my single upvote was +10 reputation.  You lost 2 whole reputation points from was a bad answer, which I upvoted, to make a sarcastic response.  In fact you received 20 reputation but only lost 10 so your actually ahead by 10.

Comment: Sorry I miscalculated.  You earned +45 reputation from the answer but lost 12 reputation from it.  So you gained a net total of 32 reputation from your answer that people didn't even like....

Comment: @nixkuroi *"I can't remove it because it might be hurting people to not be able to find it"* No, those are just reasons you *probably shouldn't* remove it. The reason you *can't* remove it is because it has a positively scored answer.

Answer (score 6):

> Is this a valid reason for a down vote?

Yes. Maybe. Perhaps. I don't know.

I mean... there is simply no such thing "valid reason for a down vote", at least not something that can/should be enforced.

The power of Stack Exchange sites is that each and every user is free to vote as they see fit. Starting to limit this and binding this to rules will render it almost useless.

Of course there are limits and red lines, e.g. a user who downvotes many posts of other user in short period of time, which is often done as sheer revenge. But user who downvote posts they deem as bad, for whatever reason, is legit.

Comment: You need to edit this to say “Yes. Maybe. Perhaps. I don't know — _get off my back!”_

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens sorry, not sure what you mean and you're wrong. Users are also free to upvote. And same as with downvotes, if one user upvotes lots of posts of one other user, this is detected and reversed.